# Most interesting mathematics mistake?

Tags: soft-question, big-list, gm.general-mathematics

Some mistakes in mathematics made by extremely smart and famous people can eventually lead to interesting developments and theorems, e.g. Poincaré's 3d sphere characterization or the search to prove that Euclid's parallel axiom is really <s>necessary</s> unnecessary.

But I also think there are less famous mistakes worth hearing about. So, here's a question:

> What's the most interesting mathematics mistake that you know of?

EDIT: There is a similar question which has been closed as a duplicate to this one, but which also garnered some new answers. It can be found here:

[Failures that lead eventually to new mathematics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/77425/failures-that-lead-eventually-to-new-mathematics)

Comment: Yeah, I've also been thinking there should be a tag like "not-math-related" -- perhaps "meta", if that's doesn't suggest 'related to the operation of MO' too narrowly.

Comment: 'meta' is kind of reserved keyword which indeed refers to things like `meta.stackoverflow.com`. I'm thinking about `soft-questions`. Is it a good idea?

Comment: doesn't "cycling back to the front page" could also mean that it is still of interest? e.g. this one has been just been edited and therefore got to the front page again. Therefore it gets closed??? I don't get the logic behind that...

Comment: Well, cycling well-viewed topics back to the front comes at the cost of pushing newer questions out of immediate visibility faster, so I understand the motivation.  On the other hand, as the site grows, we get new perspectives on old questions which, and as vonjd points out, are apparently still of interest.  We shouldn't close things just because the site old-timers are tired of seeing them.  This discussion is probably on meta somewhere already....

Comment: I agree with Cam - and in this case additionally: the big-list-tag means it is a big list and it can only become a big-list because many people make it a big list - so to close big-lists because they became big-lists is kind of absurd. Perhaps the underlying mechanism of bringing things to the front page should be changed in the software then. Just closing it is no solution

Comment: A discussion thread was started on meta partly inspired by this: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/284/why-was-my-question-closed-section-in-the-faq/#Item_1.

Comment: Cassini expected his ovals could describe planetary orbits around two big masses ... later found incorrect.

Comment: "Interesting mistake" has more than one dimension. I published a paper (long ago) about a theory, where I assumed a better definition than the actual one -- I was sure that mine was the original definition. And I mechanically typed in the original definition; possibIy, I automatically modified it, but in either case, I was sure that I was using the original definition, and that's what I claimed.

Comment: I wanted to post my favourite, very poignant story about Edward Nelson proving the inconsistency of arithmetic and Terence Tao proving him wrong, if somebody would please upvote this comment

Answer (score 239):

C.N. Little listing the [Perko pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perko_pair) as different knots in 1885 (10<sub>161</sub> and 10<sub>162</sub>). The mistake was found almost a century later, in 1974, by Ken Perko, a NY lawyer (!)
For almost a century, when everyone thought they were different knots, people tried their best to find knot invariants to distinguish them, but of course they failed. But the effort was a major motivation to research covering linkage etc., and was surely tremendously fruitful for knot theory.
[image] [<sup>(source)</sup>](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-gif/PerkoPair_1000.gif)

---

**Update (2013):**
This morning I received a letter from Ken Perko himself, revealing the true history of the Perko pair, which is so much more interesting! Perko writes:

> The duplicate knot in tables compiled by Tait-Little [3], Conway [1], and Rolfsen-Bailey-Roth [4], is not just a bookkeeping error. It is a counterexample to an 1899 "Theorem" of C.N. Little (Yale PhD, 1885), accepted as true by P.G. Tait [3], and incorporated by Dehn and Heegaard in their important survey article on "Analysis situs" in the German Encyclopedia of Mathematics [2].

Little's `Theorem' was that any two reduced diagrams of the same knot possess the same writhe (number of overcrossings minus number of undercrossings). The Perko pair have different writhes, and so Little's "Theorem", if true, would prove them to be distinct!

Perko continues:

> Yet still, after 40 years, learned scholars do not speak of Little's false theorem, describing instead its decapitated remnants as a [Tait Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tait_conjectures)- and indeed, one subsequently proved correct by Kauffman, Murasugi, and Thistlethwaite.

I had no idea! Perko concludes (boldface is my own):

> **I think they are missing a valuable point. History instructs by reminding the reader not merely of past triumphs, but of terrible mistakes as well.**

And the final nail in the coffin is that **the image above isn't of the Perko pair**!!! It's the `Weisstein pair' $10_{161}$ and mirror $10_{163}$, described by Perko as  "those magenta colored, almost matching non-twins that add beauty and confusion to the Perko Pair page of Wolfram Web’s Math World website. In a way, it’s an honor to have my name attached to such a well-crafted likeness of a couple of Bhuddist prayer wheels, but it certainly must be treated with the caution that its color suggests by anyone seriously interested in mathematics."

The real Perko pair is this:

[image]

You can read more about this fascinating story at [Richard Elwes's blog](https://richardelwes.co.uk/2013/08/14/the-revenge-of-the-perko-pair/).

Well, I'll be jiggered! The most interesting mathematics mistake that I know turns out to be more interesting than I had ever imagined!

---

1. J.H. Conway, *An enumeration of knots and links, and some of their algebraic properties*, Proc. Conf. Oxford, 1967, p. 329-358 (Pergamon Press, 1970).
2. M. Dehn and P. Heegaard, Enzyk. der Math. Wiss. III AB 3 (1907), p. 212: "Die algebraische Zahl der Ueberkreuzungen ist fuer die reduzierte Form jedes Knotens bestimmt."

3. C.N. Little, *Non-alternating +/- knots*, Trans. Roy. Soc. Edinburgh **39** (1900), page 774 and plate III. This paper describes itself at p. 771 as "Communicated by Prof. Tait."

4. D. Rolfsen, *Knots and links* (Publish or Perish, 1976).

Comment: That's a nice mistake.  Do you know how it started -- presumably at some point the knots were separated by a flawed computation of some invariant?  

Comment: Little (with Tait and Kirkman) compiled his tables combinatorially. He drew all possible 4-valent graphs with some number of vertices (in this case 10), and resolved 4-valent vertices into crossings in all possible ways. He ended up with 2<sup>10</sup> knots. Then he worked BY HAND to eliminate doubles, by making physical models with string. He failed to bring these two knots to the same position, and concluded that they must be different. It took almost 100 years to find the ambient isotopy which shows that there are the same knot, but the quest to show they are different was fruitful.

Comment: Did Conway assume they were different as well, or did the mistake persist for other reasons, like an error in computing an invariant?

Comment: Yes- Conway assumed they were different in his table as well, but had no invariant to prove it. I don't know of any miscalculated invariant which "showed" they were different.

Comment: Ryan- you were right. See the update!

Comment: +1 for the update that shows that there was a mistake wrapped in a mistake hidden in a mistake. :)

Comment: Ken Perko attempted to make another edit, by adding the following to the citation of Conway's paper: CONWAY WAS NOT MISLED BY THIS FALSE THEOREM OF C.N.LITTLE. HE FOUND THREE COUNTEREXAMPLES AMONG HIS 11-CROSSING NON-ALTERNATING KNOTS AND CORRECTLY WEEDED OUT THE DUPLICATE KNOT TYPES. Cf. Hoste-Thistlethwaite-Weeks, The first 1,701,936 knots, Math. Intelligencer 20 (1998) FOOTNOTE 8 and Jablan-Radovic-Saxdanovic, Adequacy of link fanilies, Publictiones de L'Institute Mathematique, Nouvelle Serie, Tome 88(102) (2010), 21-52.

Comment: (Perko's comment continues...) FOR CONWAY, KNOT THEORY WAS A HIGH SCHOOL HOBBY AND HIS CHECKING AND EXTENSION OF THE NINETEENTH CENTURY TABLES "AN AFTERNOON'S WORK." He just didn't look very closely at the 10-crossing knots.

Comment: Image for the real Perko pair is gone :(

Comment: This answer is in need of some editing. The proposed edit by Perko should definitely be included, and the picture of the Perko pair should be restored.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე FTFY (meaning: "Fixed that for you" -- for civilians like myself -- Todd Trimble).

Comment: @DanielMoskovich Could you take a look at this question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3036870/perko-pair-whats-the-handedness-of-these-pictures

Comment: Ken Perko is doing maths again: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Ken_Perko

Answer (score 138):

An error of Lebesgue.  1905 or so.  Take a Borel set in the plane, project it onto a line, the result is a Borel set.  Obvious: the projection of an open set is open, and the Borel sets in the plane are the least family containing the open sets, closed under countable unions and countable decreasing intersections.

But wrong.  Projection doesn't commute with countable decreasing intersection.

Studying this error led Suslin to begin the line of study now called "descriptive set theory", 1917 or so.

Comment: Projection doesn't even commute with finite intersection.

Comment: To generate Borel sets, it is enough to use countable decreasing intersections.  Will correct.

Comment: The story was recounted by Kazimierz Kuratowski in his ``A half century of Polish mathematics." Of course neither Suslin nor his advisor Lusin were Polish, but Waclaw Sierpinski, a Polish mathematician who was interned in Russia at that time, witnessed the conversation between Suslin and Lusin in which the student communicated the discovery to the professor.

Comment: @domotorp But projection does commute with finite decreasing intersections :)

Comment: What was true about the projection? 1) Was it continuous? 2) Was it open?. Which paper if good to read about it?

Comment: @ged ... the projection of $\mathbb R^2$ onto $\mathbb R$ is defined as: $P(x,y) = x$.  Yes, P is continuous and open.

Answer (score 117):

All of the (in retrospect) misguided attempts to prove Euclid's Parallel Postulate, which eventually led Gauss to develop hyperbolic geometry.

Comment: (and/or Lobachevsky, and/or Bolyai)

This gets my vote as one of the most fruitful mistakes, and one of the longest perpetuated.

Comment: They were not all misguided. Some (many?) of those attempts turned out to be steps in the theory of the hyperbolic plane, i.e. implications of the form $P \implies Q$ where $P$ is the denial of the parallel postulate, and $Q$ is what turns out to be an interesting property of the hyperbolic plane. Yes, the author might go on to say "$Q$ is CLEARLY false" and from that deduce that the parallel postulate was true, but later readers would learn something and progress further.

Answer (score 98):

Kempe's "proof" of the four-color theorem, which didn't prove the four-color theorem, but did:

1. Prove the *five*-color theorem
2. Somehow manage to go unnoticed for a dozen years
3. Lay the foundations for major tools in structural graph theory, and despite being fundamentally flawed, serve as the starting point for the eventual successful proof(s) of 4CT.

Comment: The news of that "proof" was even given in an Iranian public newspaper at the time when a few Iranian (could) read anything but religious texts!

Answer (score 76):

It was "proved" in 1961 that the first right derived functor, $\lim^1_{\leftarrow}$ of the inverse limit functor is zero on Mittag-Leffler systems.

However, recently a counter-example was found by Neeman and Deligne:

- Neeman, A. *A counterexample to a 1961 “theorem” in homological algebra*, Invent. math. 148, 397–420 (2002). doi:[10.1007/s002220100197](https://doi.org/10.1007/s002220100197), [pdf from the IAS](https://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/counterexample.pdf)

Comment: wait... really? this is serious, i use that a lot... dammnit!

Comment: Apparently all you need is that the abelian category have a set of generators, so for example it is true in the category of abelian groups. Also, my advisor, and i believe some others, use it differently then it is stated on wikipedia and in the paper... i think

Comment: Cf. http://mathoverflow.net/a/35864/27465 and jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/73/1/65. A sufficient extra structure in an abelian category for this to hold is: Grothendieck's axioms AB3, AB4* and having a set of generators. In particular, it is true in module categories (and even categories of "almost modules").

Comment: Cf. also https://mathoverflow.net/q/291151/27465.

Answer (score 70):

A story I heard in grad school:

Once upon a time, a set theorist was writing a paper on inner models, and in it he wrote, "... and we will call such models *nice*."  When he got his manuscript back from the typist (this was back in the pre-LaTeX days of technical typists), he saw that his handwriting had been misread, and the line came out as: "... and we will call such models *mice*."  The name stuck, and to this day if you browse almost any recent volume of the *Journal of Symbolic Logic,* you will find set theory articles on "mice."

Comment: I've heard a version of this story too, but I've also heard that Jensen denied that this was the origin of "mice".  I never asked Jensen himself about it, so I don't know what to believe.

Comment: You know what will be a great paper title? "Of mice and men"

Comment: Note that this story [is not true](http://mathoverflow.net/a/1274/52890).

Answer (score 61):

Maybe it's not true, but there's the story of the "Grothendieck prime":

> One striking characteristic of Grothendieck's mode of thinking is that it seemed to rely so little on examples. This can be seen in the legend of the so-called "Grothendieck prime". In a mathematical conversation, someone suggested to Grothendieck that they should consider a particular prime number. "You mean an actual number?" Grothendieck asked. The other person replies, yes, an actual prime number. Grothendieck suggested, "All right, take 57."
>
> But Grothendieck must have known that 57 is not prime, right? Absolutely not, said David Mumford of Brown University. "He doesn’t think concretely."

from here: http://www.ams.org/notices/200410/fea-grothendieck-part2.pdf

Comment: But does this qualify as an *interesting* mistake?

Comment: @Todd, yes, in the sense that it is a *fun* mistake.

Comment: @Joël I agree that it's an amusing mistake, but I was reading the question more in terms of mistakes that led to interesting developments (and I think the highest voted answers went with that reading).

Comment: I was told this story by my lecturer in a graduate algebra course back in 2015, except the lecturer ended with the punchline "All right, take 59". There was a dead silence for about three seconds until we all realized what had happened and everyone started laughing.

Comment: Grothendieck was not the first eminent mathematician to give 57 as an example of a prime. Hermann Weyl (American Mathematical Monthly 1951, p.532) mentioned Goldbach's conjecture about "primes of the smallest possible difference 2, like 57 and 59."

Comment: @JohnStillwell: this seems to attribute the twin prime conjecture to Goldbach.  This would seem to also be a mistake - see e.g. http://www.math.sjsu.edu/~goldston/twinprimes.pdf , which credits the conjecture to de Polignac.

Answer (score 59):

Poincare defined the fundamental group and the homology groups and proved that $H_1$ was $\pi _1$ abelianized. So the question came up whether there were other groups $\pi_n$ whose abelianization would give the $H_n$. Cech defined the higher $\pi_n$ as a proposed answer and submitted a paper on this. But Alexandroff and Hopf got the paper, proved that the higher $\pi_n$ were abelian and thus not the solution, and they persuaded Cech to withdraw the paper. Nevertheless a short note appeared and the $\pi_n$ started to be studied anyway...

Taken from http://www.intlpress.com/hha/v1/n1/a1/ ,page 17

Answer (score 59):

From Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence), about uniform convergence:

"Augustin Louis Cauchy in 1821 published a faulty proof of the false statement that the pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions is always continuous. Joseph Fourier and Niels Henrik Abel found counter examples in the context of Fourier series. Dirichlet then analyzed Cauchy's proof and found the mistake: the notion of pointwise convergence had to be replaced by uniform convergence."

Comment: I have always loved that way Abel wrote this (in a footnote): «it appears to me that this theorem suffers exceptions»... 

Comment: Some (e.g. A. Robinson) say that this is a mis-interpretation of the situation.  When Cauchy says the sequence converges *at all points* this includes infinitesimals and such things not recognized as real numbers nowadays.  Abel's counterexample $\sum (1/n) \sin(nx)$ in fact *does not converge* at certain points $x$ infinitely close to $0$.  We can hardly fault Cauchy if he did not use the notion of real number from Dedekind and Cantor, since that would not come until 50 years later.

Answer (score 59):

An insignificant mistake, but amusing nonetheless: in Cayley's famous 1854 paper where he defines the concept of an abstract group, as an illustration he proves that there are *three* groups of order 6 (up to isomorphism). This is because he does not realize that the groups $Z_2\times Z_3$ and $Z_6$ are isomorphic.

This is found on page 51 of A. Cayley, Desiderata and suggestions: No. 1. The theory of groups, American J. Math. 1 (1878), 50-52. An interesting related paper is G. A. Miller, Contradictions in the literature of group theory, American Math. Monthly 29 (1922), 319-328.

Comment: Very nice one and very much in spirit of computer bugs!

Comment: Iǘe had a couple of students who are now going to be proud! :P

Comment: Can you provide a reference?  I just checked his paper "On the theory of groups, as depending on the symbolic equation θ^n = 1" (1854) which Wikipedia gives as the first definition of an abstract group.  He says, "And we have thus two, and only two, essentially distinct forms of a group of six", and then gives their Cayley tables.  The paper I was reading is http://pdfserve.informaworld.com/26005_751318052_910849049.pdf linked from http://www.informaworld.com/smpp/content~content=a910849049&db=all

Comment: It took me a while to track down the correct reference. It is page 51 of A. Cayley, Desiderta and suggestions: No. 1. The theory of groups, American J. Math. 1 (1878), 50-52. An interesting related paper is G. A. Miller, Contradictions in the literature of group theory, American Math. Monthly 29 (1922), 319-328.

Comment: An understandable mistake: At that time there were no Chinese restaurants in Cambridge, I guess!

Answer (score 56):

Frege's proposed axioms in *Die Grundgesetze der Arithmetik.*

Frege was trying to derive the concept of "number" from more basic concepts, and he tried to axiomatize higher-order logic (essentially, a kind of set theory), but his intuitive-seeming axioms were logically inconsistent.  Russell first found the inconsistency, which we now call Russell's Paradox.

In fairness to Frege, he was suspicious of his flawed axiom, before Russell wrote to him about his paradox. In the introduction he writes:

> "If we find everything in order, then we have accurate knowledge of
>   the grounds upon which each individual theorem is based. A dispute can
>   arise, so far as I can see, only with regard to my Basic Law
>   concerning courses-of-values (V), which logicians perhaps have not yet
>   expressly enunciated, and yet is what people have in mind, for
>   example, where they speak of the extensions of concepts."

Comment: +1, although I don't see this as a "mistake" in the sense of the other examples. He didn't do what he intended, but he wasn't wrong at any point. An inconsistent formal system is a perfectly fine mathematical setup, just one that people are mostly uninterested in.

Answer (score 47):

Not just a great mistake, but also a great *documentation* of a mistake: Stallings's [How not to prove the Poincare Conjecture](http://math.berkeley.edu/%7Estall/notPC.pdf).<sup>1</sup> (I think this paper is my answer to every community-wiki question.)

<sup>1</sup>Here is a [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20140630032821/http://math.berkeley.edu/%7Estall/notPC.pdf) link.

Comment: Whitehead's similar mistake is very interesting, too, as it lead him to the construction of contractible 3-manifolds that aren't balls. 

Comment: There is also a paper by Cartier with a similar title: "Comment l'hypothèse de Riemann ne fut pas prouvée."

Comment: Stallings's page went down. The paper is at https://web.archive.org/web/20140630032821/http://math.berkeley.edu/~stall/notPC.pdf

Answer (score 46):

I believe Kummer's failed attempt at a proof of Fermat's last theorem led to the discovery of ideals.

Comment: I'm told that Kummer actually didn't care about Fermat's last theorem; it just happened that the techniques he developed were applicable.

Comment: It was actually Lame who came up with that bad proof.

Comment: Oh, ok my mistake.

Comment: Harold Edwards wrote a wonderful account of this history in his paper "The background of Kummer's proof of Fermat's last theorem for regular primes". It doesn't seem to be available online, but the mathsci net review is: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=57:12066a

Comment: I don't know whether it is appropriate to say "discovery" of ideals. Maybe "recognition of the importance/relevance of ideals"?

Answer (score 45):

Pontryagin made a famous mistake while computing the stable homotopy groups of spheres (specifically, π<sub>2</sub>) which led to the discovery of the Kervaire invariant.  I won't spoil what the mistake was: watch this [video](https://www.simonsfoundation.org/news/-/asset_publisher/bo1E/content/mathematicians-solve-45-year-old-kervaire-invariant-puzzle) of Mike Hopkins' talk (second video on the page), starting about 7 minutes in.

Comment: A mistake in a close field (I can't do another answer): before Milnor, everybody thought it obvious that two topological *n*-spheres could have different structures as differentiable manifolds. I'm pretty sure Milnor himself thought he made a mistake when some invariant turned out to be different for two topological spheres. For details, see the third volume of his collected papers.

Comment: @IlyaGrigoriev: Do you mean "before Milnor, everybody thought it obvious that two topological n-spheres could NOT have different structures as differentiable manifolds"?

Comment: @JimConant: Yes, of course.

Comment: I am glad this mistake had some good consequence.  i had only heard that it delayed Bott's proof of his periodicity theorem, since it seemed to contradict that result.

Comment: @roysmith: I think you're mixing a couple of stories. The computation of $\pi_2$ was sorted out by 1950, probably much earlier, but certainly before Bott had really started down the path to periodicity. See Pontrjagin's 1950 paper, Homotopy classification of the mappings of an (n+2)-dimensional sphere on an n-dimensional one, or G. Whitehead (Ann. of Math. 52 (1950)). Eckmann's review of the former clearly indicates the role of the Arf invariant. There were early homotopy theory calculations that seemed to contradict Bott periodicity; Bott tells the story in various autobiographical pieces.

Comment: Thank you Danny!  I have now read more in detail from talks by Bott and see that he mentions a controversy over the correct value of the 10th! homotopy group of U, as inspiring his interest.   https://ac.els-cdn.com/0001870870900307/1-s2.0-0001870870900307-main.pdf?_tid=1f734ed0-fa90-4d4a-9e1c-e2a59ee5e179&acdnat=1522258790_f6fded1ff11e00dece8e72883713de71

Answer (score 42):

Supposedly Stefan Bergman attended a course on orthogonal functions while an undergraduate, and misunderstood what he was hearing, believing that the functions were supposed to be analytic. This led him to the Bergman kernel and Hilbert spaces of analytic functions, which has developed into a whole field of study at the junction of complex analysis and operator theory, and also with important ramifications in the more geometric parts of SCV. If the story is true, this was certainly an extremely fruitful mistake!

Comment: Paul Cohen told a version this story in his Complex Analysis class at Stanford when I was a graduate student.

Answer (score 39):

Poincaré's discovery of homoclinic points grew out of a extremely serious mistake he made in his original submission for a prize essay contest sponsored by Acta Mathematica in 1888. His original 200 page manuscript, on the restricted three-body problem, was evaluated by Weierstrass, Mittag-Leffler, and Phragmén, who had great difficulty following his arguments. Poincaré responded with a dozen further explanations, totaling 100 pages. After many further exchanges, the editors finally decided to accept the manuscript (this was, after all, Poincaré, and he must know what he's doing) and awarded him the prize.

But around the time of publication, Phragmén was still puzzled by some points and Mittag-Leffler wrote to Poincaré. They received back a telegram from Poincaré asking that publication be stopped immediately! Poincaré realized that his belief that the stable and unstable manifolds could not intersect transversally was wrong, and that such intersection points, which he later called homoclinic points, immediately forced very complicated dynamically behavior, invalidating much of his work. He wrote to Mittag-Leffler:

> "I have written this morning to Mr. Phragmén to tell him about an error which I have committed and he has undoubtedly informed you of my letter. But the consequences of this error are more serious than I first thought. It is not true that the asymptotic surfaces are closed, at least not in the sense that I meant before. What is true, is that if one considers the two parts of that surface (which I yesterday still believed coincided with each other) they intersect along infinitely many asymptotic trajectories and furthermore their distance is an infinitesimal of higher order than $\mu^p$ however big p is.
>
> I don't conceal from you the trouble this discovery gives me."

Mittag-Leffler immediately halted the presses and recalled all copies of this issue he could get, destroying them all (except for a few, one of which remains in the library of the Mittag-Leffler Institute). They asked Poincare to pay for the suppression of this issue, which he did.

Poincare then wrote a new essay, incorporating many of the added notes from the original, and this was the version that Acta Mathematica published (with no mention of the earlier one). Eventually Poincaré used this as the basis of his three volume classic *Les méthodes nouvelles de la mécanique céleste*.

A riveting account of this story is contained in *Poincaré's discovery of homoclinic points* by K. G. Anderson, Archive History of Exact Sciences, 48(2) (1994), 133–147.

Comment: And, apparently, Poincaré had to spend (all or most of) his prize money to pay for the destruction and reprinting of that _Acta_ issue. Would be good to get an authoritative source for this.

Comment: The article by K. G. Anderson cited above does give authoritative account of these issues. It's not clear how much of Poincare'd prize was spent on the recall however.

Answer (score 34):

Steiner's count 7776 of the number of the number of plane conics tangent to 5 general plane conics certainly deserves a mention here. He gave this answer in 1848, and it wasn't fixed until 1864, when Chasles pointed out the error and came up with the correct value of 3264. You can regard this as the first recognition of needing appropriate compactifications in order to do valid calculations in enumerative geometry.

Comment: I must add to this that this story is even linked with modern developments, in the following direction: if the 5 conics are all real, how many among the 3264 conics tangents to all 5 of them are real?
In 1997, Ronga, Tognoli and Vust found an example where all 3264 tangents conics are real. In 2005, Welschinger proved that if the 5 conics are ellipses, no two nested one inside the other, then at least 32 of the 3264 tangent conics must be real. This is related to a lot of deep modern tools.

Comment: Eisenbud and Harris consider this example so important that they named a book after the number 3264: *D. Eisenbud, J. Harris: 3264 and all that. Cambridge University Press (2016)*. In a nutshell, what is is to be appreciated in this story is that mathematicians a hundred years later succeeded in completing a formal framework which guarantees that "number of plane conics tangent to 5 general plane conics" is *well-posed*. (The deeply problematic word to make sense of in the latter is "general".)

Answer (score 29):

Goodrick's "story from Grad school" is incorrect.   According to Ronald Jensen, the set theorist in question, he felt that the concept was important enough that it deserved a name which had not already been used elsewhere in mathematics.   And 'mice' was it.  (Also, note that 'mice' is a noun, and 'nice' is an adjective --- it would not make sense.)

Comment: But the urban legend is so funny...

Comment: I have heard 3 versions of the origin of the name. They all originated with Jensen, and were told at a rate of one per decade. Last I checked, he actually does not seem to remember the reason for the name.

Comment: I haven't even questioned the origins of the term until now... somehow it just made perfect sense in my head that inner models be called "mice" because they're small or something \_:)_/

Answer (score 27):

Hilbert's program, whose development was induced by on assumptions shattered by Gödel.

Comment: Just stumbled over this answer, and would like to point out that this sentence 'does not parse', as they say. I will not touch it, out of respect to any writing which is not technically-wrong, yet it might be good if you reformulated it. The 'shattered' is a bit extreme, by the way. And in case you don't have umlauts ready, here is an ö to copy and paste. @Thomas Riepe

Comment: I think "induced by" could be replaced by "founded" and then it would read sensibly.

Answer (score 23):

Perhaps not under this heading but I enjoy reading in Marshall Hall Group Theory book:

"Let p be any old prime."

Comment: I can't find this in my copy of Hall's book :-( Google led me to a suggestion that it was on "p419" but the only mention of primes on p419 of my copy is in the middle of Theorem 20.9.13 where it's an odd prime. I have the second printing (published 1976). Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: @eric the mistake is indeed "old" instead if "odd" in the first edition!

Comment: Scott Turow, who is perhaps the most prominent author in the genre of "legal thrillers", wrote "delivered through the mouth of June", and a copy editor "corrected" what was thought to be a typographical error, so that the published book says "delivered through the month of June." But "mouth" is correct, i.e. June was the person who orally transmitted the information.

Answer (score 22):

Bringing in sort of tragic flavor to this question, - the following came to my mind:

> He was not a very careful person as a mathematician. He made a lot of mistakes. But he made mistakes in a good direction. I tried to imitate him. But I've realized that it's very difficult to make good mistakes.

(Shimura on [Taniyama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yutaka_Taniyama#Depression_and_death), seen it in the "BBC Horizon Season 1996 Episode 2 - Fermat's Last Theorem" [available on Youtube](https://youtu.be/wRgurZawQNE?t=11m29s))

Comment: This quotation can be found in print (with slightly different wording and punctuation) in Shimura's obituary of Taniyama in the Bull. London Math. Soc., March 1989, p. 190.

Comment: Shimura wrote: "Though he was by no means the sloppy type, he was gifted with the special capability of making many mistakes, mostly in the right direction. I envied him for this, and tried in vain to imitate him, but found it quite difficult to make good mistakes."

Answer (score 22):

**Foias constant** also comes from a mistake. I quote directly from *An interesting serendipitous real number* by John Ewing and Ciprian Foias:

> This is the story of a remarkable real number, the discovery of which was
> due to a misprint. Namely, in the midseventies, while Ciprian was at the
> University of Bucharest, one of his former students approached him with
> the following question:

> (Q) If $x_1>0$ and $x_{n+1}=\left(1+\frac1{x_n}\right)^n$ $(n= 1,2, ... )$, can $x_n\rightarrow\infty$?

> This was listed in a fall issue of the "Gazeta Matematica" as one of
> the problems given at the previous summer admission examination for
> prospective freshmen in the Department of Mathematics at the University
> of Bucharest. Ciprian found the answer in about one day, but considered
> that the problem was even above the sophomore level. He also found that
> (Q) is a misprinted version of the following question (given by Professor N.
> Boboc):

> (Q') If $x_1>0$ and $x_{n+1}=\left(1+\frac1{x_n}\right)^{x_n}$ $(n= 1,2, ... )$, can $x_n\rightarrow\infty$?

> This was an appropriate exam question since the answer is clearly "No."
> Years later, in the 1980s, Ciprian told the story to Professor P. Halmos,
> who in turn told the story to John, but mischieveously did not mention
> at all Ciprian's answer to (Q), so a day later John also found the answer.
> This answer is given by the following

> **Theorem 1.1** *There exists exactly one real number $a\sim 1.187$ such that
> if $x_1=a$ then $x_n\rightarrow\infty$. Moreover in this case
> $$x_n\frac{\ln n}n\rightarrow 1 \text{ for } n\rightarrow\infty \ \ (1)$$*
> Relation (1) can be rewritten as
> $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{x_n}{\pi(n)}=1  \ \ (2)$$
> where $\pi(n)$ is the number of primes less than $n$. However after many attempts to establish a deeper connection with the Prime Number Theorem, we came to believe that relation (2) is fortuitous. A strong argument for this opinion is provided by Theorem 3.1 below in which we show that the estimate for the error
> $$x_n\frac{\ln n}n-1$$
> differs from its analog in the Prime Number Theorem.

*An interesting serendipitous real number*. J. Ewing, C. Foias.
*Finite versus infinite. Contributions to an eternal dilemma*. Springer (2000), pages 119-126.

Answer (score 21):

In chapter 3 of **What Is Mathematics, Really?** (pages 43-45), Prof. Hersh writes:

> How is it possible that mistakes occur in mathematics?
>
> René Descartes's Method was so clear, he said, a mistake could only happen by inadvertence. Yet, ... his Géométrie contains conceptual mistakes about three-dimensional space.
>
> Henri Poincaré said it was strange that mistakes happen in mathematics, since mathematics is just sound reasoning, such as anyone in his right mind follows. His explanation was memory lapse—there are only so many things we can keep in mind at once.
>
> Wittgenstein said that mathematics could be characterized as the subject where it's possible to make mistakes. (Actually, it's not just possible, it's inevitable.) The very notion of a mistake presupposes that there is right and wrong independent of what we think, which is what makes mathematics mathematics. We mathematicians make mistakes, even important ones, even in famous papers that have been around for years.
>
> Philip J. Davis displays an imposing collection of errors, with some famous names. His article shows that mistakes aren't uncommon. It shows that mathematical knowledge is fallible, like other knowledge.
>
> ...
>
> Some mistakes come from keeping old assumptions in a new context.
>
> Infinite dimensional space is just like finite dimensional space—except for one or two properties, which are entirely different.
>
> ...
>
> Riemann stated and used what he called "Dirichlet's principle" incorrectly [when trying to prove *his* mapping theorem].
>
> Julius König and David Hilbert each thought he had proven the continuum hypothesis. (Decades later, it was proved undecidable by Kurt Gödel and Paul Cohen.)
>
> Sometimes mathematicians try to give a *complete classification* of an object of interest. It's a mistake to claim a complete classification while leaving out several cases. That's what happened, first to Descartes, then to Newton, in their attempts to classify cubic curves (Boyer). [*cf*. [**this**](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44244/what-recent-discoveries-have-amateur-mathematicians-made/44248#44248) annotation by Peter Shor.]
>
> Is a gap in a proof a mistake? Newton found the speed of a falling stone by dividing 0/0. Berkeley called him to account for bad algebra, but admitted Newton had the right answer... Mistake or not?
>
> ...
>
> "The mistakes of a great mathematician are worth more than the correctness of a mediocrity." I've heard those words more than once. Explicating this thought would tell something about the nature of mathematics. For most academic philosopher of mathematics, this remark has nothing to do with mathematics or the philosophy of mathematics. Mathematics for them is indubitable—rigorous deductions from premises. If you made a mistake, your deduction wasn't rigorous, By definition, then, it wasn't mathematics!
>
> So the brilliant, fruitful mistakes of Newton, Euler, and Riemann, weren't mathematics, and needn't be considered by the philosopher of mathematics.
>
> Riemann's incorrect statement of Dirichlet's principle was corrected, implemented, and flowered into the calculus of variations. On the other hand, thousands of *correct* theorems are published every week. Most lead nowhere.
>
> A famous oversight of Euclid and his students (don't call it a mistake) was neglecting the relation of "between-ness" of points on a line. This relation was used *implicitly* by Euclid in 300 B.C. It was recognized *explicitly* by Moritz Pasch over 2,000 years later, in 1882. *For two millennia, mathematicians and philosophers accepted reasoning that they later rejected.*
>
> Can we be sure that we, unlike our predecessors, are not overlooking big gaps? We can't. Our mathematics can't be certain.

The reference to the said article by Philip J. Davis is:

Fidelity in mathematical discourse: Is one and one really two? *Amer. Math. Monthly* **79** (1972), 252–263.

From that article, I find particularly amusing the following couple of paragraphs from page 262:

> There is a book entitled *Erreurs de Mathématiciens*, published by Maurice Lecat in 1935 in Brussels. This book contains more than 130 pages of errors committed by mathematicians of the first and second rank from antiquity to about 1900.There are parallel columns listing the mathematician, the place where his error occurs, the man who discovers the error, and the place where the error is discussed. For example, J. J. Sylvester committed an error in "On the Relation between the Minor Determinant of Linearly Equivalent Quadratic Factors", Philos. Mag., (1851) pp. 295-305. This error was corrected by H. E. Baker in the *Collected Papers of Sylvester*, Vol. I, pp. 647-650.
>
> ...
>
> A mathematical error of international significance may occur every twenty years or so. By this I mean the conjunction a mathematician of great reputation and a problem of great notoriety. Such a conjunction occurred around 1945 when H. Rademacher thought he had solved the Riemann Hypothesis. There was a report in *Time* magazine.

Comment: IIRC, one reason this is interesting is that this got people looking at calculus of variations in more detail/anxiety than had been done previously (i.e. in arguments where one assumed a minimizing function existed, and then used properties of said function, it wasn't always clear that a minimizer existed)

Comment: Re Poincaré's explanation: IMHO, it's frequently not just memory lapse, but just plain laziness. Whenever you see "it is obvious that", take a moment to see if it's really so obvious. I find this a useful rule of thumb when refereeing papers.

Comment: "Wittgenstein said that mathematics could be characterized as the subject where it's possible to make mistakes. (Actually, it's not just possible, it's inevitable.) The very notion of a mistake presupposes that there is right and wrong independent of what we think, which is what makes mathematics mathematics." The later Wittgenstein believed precisely the opposite of this, claiming that "the mathematician is not a discoverer: he is an inventor"

Answer (score 16):

I don't know if this is really a mistake: Fermat's "missing proof" for Fermat's last theorem.

Comment: In the absence of meaningful evidence that the linked MSE post (which merely states a conjecture) is related to Fermat's missing proof, I've reverted @BCLC's edit.

Answer (score 15):

Samuel I. Krieger made many attempts at significant contributions to the field of mathematics, unfortunately some of his efforts did not pan out.

In 1934, he claimed that the 72-digit composite number $231,584,178,474,632,390,847,141,970,017,375,815,706,593,969,331,281,128,078,915,826,259,279,871$ was the largest known prime number.

He also attempted to show that the number $2^{256}(2^{257}-1)$ was perfect, implying that $2^{257}-1$ is a prime number.  $2^{257}-1$ is actually a composite number: its smallest prime factor is $535,006,138,814,359.$

Finally, he claimed to have a counter example to Fermat's Last Theorem $x^n + y^n = z^n$ using the numbers $x = 1324, y = 731$ and $z = 1961$ with an undisclosed $n.$  A reporter supposedly called Krieger to ask how the left and the right hand side could be equal, when the left hand side could only end in a $4$ or a $6$ plus $1,$ and the right hand side could only end in $1.$

Comment: A *reporter* who knew about *modulo 10 arithmetics*, now that's quite a story!

Comment: I believe his 1935 claim for a much larger prime number is also incorrect:

http://news.google.com/newspapers?id=r7JQAAAAIBAJ&sjid=HiIEAAAAIBAJ&pg=6727%2C4545710

https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwVjj0KwmAUBHshd0ip3fvdt1t4FiuLFELQ-4NfymUHZs79uVfISuycpiPdxokER1JFc2xgo0yNYW01mjSOdwpwyYQqCpGdbRk9aGmmy7PsugnQzVULx3QnYjLMo6IkxkqIZHDZMAtdoK6Q7bbdjt_r_B6f9_18_AGQcSWC&lang=sage

Comment: There is a little bit more about Krieger at https://outofthenormmaths.wordpress.com/2011/11/09/blitz-krieger/ Amazon.com claims to have a book, Krieger's Mathematical Formulae, that he published in 1934, but the page also says, Out of Print--Limited Availability.

Answer (score 14):

I find this one (it is not in the same vein as the ones that have been posted here so far, this is not a pure math mistake) to be interesting and instructive to students:
[patriot missile failure due to poor understanding of binary decimals](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&client=safari&rls=en&q=patriot+missile+failure+binary)

Answer (score 14):

Petrovskiĭ-Landis solution to the second part of Hilbert 16th problem.
They "proved" the existence of a bound for the number of limit cycles
of planar polynomial vector fields of fixed degree. Ilyashenko pointed
out the mistake.

The problem remains wide open but the basic idea of Petrovskiĭ-Landis ( complexification of real differential equations )
lead to the study of holomorphic foliations.

Answer (score 13):

Lakatos' work "Proof and refutation" contains many examples of mistakes concerning the development of Euler's polyhedron formula, along with an extensive treatment of what mistakes are and how they can crucially contribute to the development of mathematics.

Answer (score 9):

Then there's always the [Martian Climate Orbiter Newtons vs Pounds of thrust embarrassment.](https://www.thefreelibrary.com/Math+error+equals+loss+of+Mars+orbiter-a057155808)

Comment: Canadians use kilometers per hour for speeds on highways, and inches and feet for building construction and heights of persons, and Celsius for weather and Fahrenheit for cooking. In the early 1980s when conversion from pounds to kilograms was causing some confusions, Air Canada flight 143 from Montreal to Edmonton was provided with 23000 pounds of fuel where 23000 kilograms had been called for. It ran out of fuel over Manitoba and had to glide without fuel to a decomissioned air force base.

Answer (score 9):

For surfaces of constant mean curvature, it is alleged that Hopf thought that all compact CMC surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$ were round spheres.  CMC surfaces are what you get if you have a soap film bounding a fixed volume, so after a childhood full of blowing bubbles this is a pretty reasonable thing to think.  And it even happens to be mostly true: Hopf proved that immersed CMC spheres are round, and Alexandrov proved with a nice reflection argument that *embedded* CMC surfaces of any genus must actually be round spheres.

But a bit later, Wente discovered a collection of CMC tori.  Ivan Sterling has some nice pictures of these [on his website](http://faculty.smcm.edu/isterling/tof/), as does [MSRI](http://www.msri.org/about/sgp/jim/geom/cmc/library/wente/index.html).  There are many very pretty connections between these surfaces and algebraic geometry, so to me they sort of mark the start of the modern "integrable systems" era of CMC research.

I should probably add that nobody actually seems sure if Hopf believed that compact CMC surfaces are spheres, but it makes a good creation story for the subfield!

Comment: The second link (MSRI) seems to be down. I have checked what is shown [in the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20061031220702/http://www.msri.org:80/about/sgp/jim/geom/cmc/library/wente/index.html). The pictures seems to be missing there, but it has a link to [this page](http://math.utoledo.edu/wente_torus.html) ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20210425235448/http://math.utoledo.edu/wente_torus.html)).

Answer (score 9):

Euler conjectured that there were no pairs of orthogonal Latin squares for orders $n \equiv 2 (\text{mod}~ 4)$.  Nearly two hundred years later, this was proved false for every $n \equiv 2 (\text{mod}~ 4)$ except $ 2 $ and $ 6 $.  [Here](http://math.dartmouth.edu/~euler/pages/E530.html)'s the link to Euler's paper.  Regardless, Euler's work certainly helped spur research into Latin squares.

Comment: It seems odd to call a conjecture a mistake.

Answer (score 8):

A wonderful mistake, which paved the way to singular cardinals, was done by Felix Bernstein in his dissertation. I learnt this from Menachem Kojman. Berstein thought he had proved that for every ordinal $\alpha$, $\aleph_\alpha^\omega=\aleph_\alpha \cdot 2^{\aleph_0}$. This is true for every $\alpha < \omega$ but already fails for $\alpha=\omega$. Berstein's mistake was to assume that every cardinal has an immediate predecessor.

Kőnig later used Berstein's result to prove that the continuum is not an aleph, thus disproving at once two of Cantor's main beliefs: 1) every set can be well-ordered and 2) the continuum hypothesis! He presented his result at the third International Congress of Mathematicians in Heidelberg in 1904 and the organizers cancelled all parallel session to allow all participants (which included Cantor and Hilbert) to attend Kőnig's lecture. And his discovery was even reported in the local news!

Here is Kőnig's reasoning:

First he proves the correct result that for every ordinal $\beta$, $\aleph_{\beta+\omega}^\omega>\aleph_{\beta+\omega}$ (a special case of what is now known as Kőnig's Theorem). He then reasons that if the continuum were an aleph, say $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_\beta$, then substituting $\alpha=\beta+\omega$ into Berstein's result one obtains that $\aleph_{\beta+\omega}^\omega=\aleph_{\beta+\omega} \cdot 2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_{\beta+\omega}$, which is a contradiction!

Comment: For some additional details, see [MR3409864](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3409864). Kojman, Menachem. *[Singular cardinals: from Hausdorff's gaps to Shelah's PCF theory](https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-444-51621-3.50007-4)*. In **[Sets and extensions in the twentieth century](https://www.elsevier.com/books/sets-and-extensions-in-the-twentieth-century/gabbay/978-0-444-51621-3)**, 509–558, Handb. Hist. Log., 6, Elsevier/North-Holland, Amsterdam, 2012.

Answer (score 7):

Something I came across a long time ago during my years in Oxford. A bit off a tangent, but still worth a quick read:

http://eprints.maths.ox.ac.uk/104/1/balls.pdf ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20161220235158/http://eprints.maths.ox.ac.uk/104/1/balls.pdf))

"If I remember rightly, cos(pi/2) = 1"

Answer (score 6):

If Hilbert's program was a "mistake", then surely so was Russell-Whitehead's Principia Mathematica.

Comment: Why? Did they claim any form of completeness?

Answer (score 6):

Certainly  not the most interesting mistake in math, but
it deserves to be mentioned.

Hesse claimed that homogeneous polynomials in $n$ variables with vanishing Hessian are, after a linear change of coordinates, polynomials in at most $n-1$ variables.

Gordan and M. Noether verified Hesse's claim for $n\le3$ and
constructed counter-examples for every $n\ge4.$

It is ironic that there is no hesitation today to call the hessian hessian.

Answer (score 5):

A mistake that isn't a mistake: in an early edition of *Number Theory* by Borevich and Shafarevich (corrected in later editions), there is a typographical error which doesn't change the meaning or correctness of the intended text, yet it is obvious that it is a typographical error. Namely, there is a table which is divided into four cases: $n\equiv 0\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 4)$, $n\equiv 1\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 4)$, $n\equiv 22\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 4)$, and $n\equiv 3\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 4)$. (I don't have a copy available, so I cannot give the precise reference.)

Comment: Do you mean an early Russian edition?  I believe the book in English only ever had one edition.  Back in the 1990s I sent the translator Newcomb Greenleaf an errata list for the English version of the book and he thanked me but said he did not expect Academic Press would ever come out with a second edition.  A genuinely bad typographical error in the English translation of that book was mentioned by me an in answer to the MO question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25263/most-squares-in-the-first-half-interval.

Comment: @KConrad: I checked that the error is on page 422 (English edition). Perhaps there is a later printing without this error; otherwise I was mistaken about it being later corrected.

Comment: I see that error in my copy, where I had just crossed out one of the 2’s in 22 to make it 2. I would not be surprised if such typos were never corrected in any later printing.

Answer (score 4):

Karl Pearson's contributions in the development of statistics are so ubiquitous that most users take his assumptions for granted.  One key contribution and mistake of his was to claim that all distributions are parametric.  Such models are still predominantly used in social and behavioral sciences, but his insistence led to a lot of interesting and very useful developments in mathematical statistics and its applications by people who published refutations of his work (like R.A. Fisher).

As a non-math mistake, Karl Pearson avidly advocated eugenics towards racial purity.  Big mistake.

Comment: Do you have a source?  I have trouble picturing why he would think that.

Comment: On your final point, Pearson was indeed part of the Eugenics movement, as were many leading statisticians and human biologists at the time, including Pearson's predecessor Galton (creator of the poorly named *regression* and much more) as well as Fisher and Haldane.  But I have not seen evidence that they advocated racial purity.

Answer (score 4):

Cantor's been mentioned, but I think the lessons there should be different.  First, the really big mistake was that of highly-reputed academics (including, I believe, Poincare, Kronecker and even Wittgenstein) who rejected his ideas.  And (related) second, even in a wiki devoted to mistakes it seems somewhat carping to fault Cantor for failing to spot a subtlety without at the same time adequately crediting his genius.

Somewhat along the same lines, one might mention Fourier's difficulties in getting his ideas accepted.

Answer (score 3):

The **Grunwald-Wang theorem**: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grunwald%E2%80%93Wang_theorem on the injectivity of $K^\times/n \to \prod K_\mathfrak{p}^\times/n$ for a global field $K$. (Proof with mistake by Grunwald in 1933, corrected by Wang in 1948, who found a counterexample, but showed that it is correct if one is not in a "special case") See also https://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/~schmidt/NSW2e/index-de.html (*Cohomology of Number Fields*) Chapter IX, especially Theorem 9.1.11.

Answer (score 3):

A posthumous book on number theory by Dirichlet appeared in 1859. It stated that Euclid's proof of the infinitude of primes was by contradiction, starting with an assumption that only finitely many primes exist and then deducing a contradiction.

Euclid's actual proof, recast in modern language, was that if $S$ is any finite set of primes (with no assumption that it constains the smallest $n$ primes nor that it contains all primes), then the prime factors of $1+\prod S$ are not members of $S;$ hence there are always more primes than what one already has.

For example, if $S=\{5,7\}$ then $1+\prod S=36=2\times2\times3\times3$ and the new primes are $2$ and $3.$

This requires no assumption that $S$ contains all primes.

Only the assumption that $S$ contains all primes could justify the conclusion that $1+\prod S$ has no prime factors, and so "is therefore itself prime", to quote G. H. Hardy (no relation to me, as far as I know) on pages 122–123 of the 1908 edition of *A Course of Pure Mathematics* (but not in the posthumous 10th edition).

The erroroneous belief that $1+\prod S$ is prime whenever $S$ is the set of the smallest $n$ primes for some $n$ has been held by some conscientious persons. The smallest (but not the only) counterexample is $1+(2\times3\times5\times7\times11\times13) = 59\times509.$

Catherine Woodgold and I examined in some detail the error of thinking that this proof is by contradiction in "Prime Simplicity", *Mathematical Intelligencer*, volume 31, number 4, Fall 2009, pages 44–52.

Answer (score 2):

William Shanks (1812-1882), who calculated pi to the 707th place, by hand, but it was only correct for the first 527 places.

Comment: But was this a fruitful mistake?

Answer (score 2):

The recent paper by Richard Brent [“Some instructive mathematical errors”](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.07269) certainly deserves a mention in this thread:

> We describe various errors in the mathematical literature, and consider how some of them might have been avoided, or at least detected at an earlier stage, using tools such as Maple or Sage. Our examples are drawn from three broad categories of errors. First, we consider some significant errors made by highly-regarded mathematicians. In some cases these errors were not detected until many years after their publication. Second, we consider in some detail an error that was recently detected by the author. This error in a refereed journal led to further errors by at least one author who relied on the (incorrect) result. Finally, we mention some instructive errors that have been detected in the author's own published papers.

Answer (score 1):

The mother of all examples: Euclid's *Elements* contains errors from start to finish.

Comment: Any examples of such errors? Any interesting ones?

Comment: The most famous is the assumption that two circles intersect in 0, 1, or 2 points. It was already seen to be buggy in ancient times (Theon or Hypatia http://www.gap-system.org/~history/Printonly/Theon.html corrected some errors), and from what I've read Hilbert did also.

Comment: Wh.. what    ??

Comment: Some poor grammar there on my part. Hilbert tried to correct Euclid's work, and needed around 20 axioms (not 5) to do so. These are seen today as being primarily topological in nature (like that the points on a line are ordered meaningfully, or that circles have insides and outsides). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_axioms 

Comment: But "*Contains errors from start to finish*", seems quite an exaggeration.

Comment: Kevin, at the risk of asking something stupid: what's the problem with circles intersecting in 0, 1, or 2 points?

Comment: @Todd, perhaps what Kevin was referring to was the assumption that, for example, the circles centered at $A$ and $B$ with radius $AB$ intersect at all. This assumes a completeness which Euclid never made explicit.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, sure, but the way my pedantic mind works: I think it's still true that over any field, two distinct circles intersect in less than three points. So I guess what you're suggesting is that there was something buggy about the description of when each of those three cases occurs (and that Kevin's description was a shorthand).

Comment: @Todd, yes, unless Kevin is thinking of something that has escaped both of us, then I think it is as you say.

Comment: That's what I had in mind, sorry for the confusion. But in my defense, can't circles on the surface of a torus have 4 intersections? And $p$-adic circles have infinitely many?

Answer (score 0):

The question above says:

> Some mistakes in mathematics made by extremely smart and famous people can eventually lead to interesting developments and theorems,

This will be a very minor example, included because the person who made the mistake is very smart and very famous, but not because it led to anything.

Take three regular pentagons sharing a vertex and three edges, as in a dodecahedron. Set it down on a horizontal mirror, so that the three edges opposite the common vertex make contact with their reflections.

These three pentagons and their mirror-images are (but are they??) six faces of a polyhedron that also has three faces that are rhombuses or rhombi or rhomboi or whatever they're called.

So Donald Knuth once thought, according to what he said in a seminar that I attended.

But the four edges of the putative rhomboi are not coplanar, so instead of those three faces you have six triangular faces.

Answer (score -3):

I think The Feynman path integral may be regarded as a great mathematical mistake, as once remarked by Richard Borcherds in a conversation.

Comment: COuld you elaborate more on this?

Comment: I don't think it was a mistake. Feynman's argument was not mathematically rigorous, but I don't think he ever claimed it was, or wanted it to be. The important thing to him, I think, was just that it gave the right answers (verifiable by experiments).

Answer (score -7):

Cantor's set theory - had he known the related paradoxes, he would probably not have started developing set theory.

Comment: Seems fairly controversial to call the development of set theory a "mistake" :)

I guess you mean that Cantor's mistake was not being careful and rigorous enough?  But then you could probably say the same thing about 18th-century analysts who played around with infinitessimals.

Comment: Yes - fortunately their intuitions had enough force to made them jump over (or blind towards) the problems (and infinitesimals may <a href="http://www.maths.nott.ac.uk/personal/ibf/rem.pdf" title="Fesenko's essay">come back</a>).
)  

Comment: Well, I think maybe he was aware: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_paradox But is there actually an identifiable mistake he made in his writings? Frege on the other hand went further, and made a mistake.