# Which journals publish short notes in discrete mathematics?

Tags: big-list, journals

The journal [Discrete Mathematics](http://www.journals.elsevier.com/discrete-mathematics/) contains a lot of short notes (i.e., less than 7 journal pages). What are some other journals that publish short notes in discrete mathematics? I've looked at other journals, but most of them seem to contain primarily long papers.

Comment: Which combinatorics journals have a policy against short papers?  None that I know of.  The question is more about the significance of the results, not the number of pages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are various *general* journals that are focused on "short papers."  There a seven pages paper would fit just fine.

Examples include, Proceedings of the AMS, Bulletin of the LMS, Archiv der Mathematik. For more you could read [Which journals publish 1-page papers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/39686/which-journals-publish-1-page-papers)
Yet, as discussed there even most other journals do not have an actual lower bound on the length of the paper; of course the paper has to be sufficiently substantive.

Furthermore, it is not that rare for a discrete mathematics paper to be short. For most journal specialized in combinatorics and discrete mathematics a paper of that length should not be anything unusual (consult the instructions for authors though).

For an overview about discrete mathematics journals see for example [Two questions about combinatorics journals](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/126507/two-questions-about-combinatorics-journals) or the respective answers on [Top specialized journals](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3512/top-specialized-journals)

Answer (score 8):

[Electronic Notes in Discrete Mathematics](http://www.journals.elsevier.com/electronic-notes-in-discrete-mathematics/) *only* publishes short notes in discrete mathematics.

Comment: But it looks like it doesn't allow direct submissions -- it is only a venue for publications from conferences.

Answer (score 7):

The [Electronic Journal of Combinatorics](http://www.combinatorics.org/) Current issue (issue 3, 2015), has the first two listed articles with $7$ and $8$ pages,
so I assume there is no page minimum requirement.

Comment: Correct.  We used to distinguish "notes" from "articles" if they were 4 pages or less, but we don't distinguish them any more.

Answer (score 6):

Also pay your attention to [Algebra and Discrete Mathematics](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/journal.phtml?jrnid=adm&wshow=details&option_lang=eng) and [Diskretnaya Matematika](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/journal.phtml?jrnid=dm&option_lang=eng).

Here is [an example](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=dm&paperid=1318&option_lang=eng). Here is [another one](http://mjcnt.phystech.edu/en/article.php?id=2).

Answer (score 4):

Discrete Mathematics Letters http://www.dmlett.com/ publishes only short notes (that is, the papers consisting of maximum 8 published pages).