# Pseudonyms of famous mathematicians

Tags: soft-question, ho.history-overview, big-list

Many mathematicians know that Lewis Carroll was quite a good mathematician, who wrote about logic (paradoxes) and determinants. He found an expansion formula, which bears his real name (Charles Lutwidge) Dodgson. Needless to say, L. Carroll was his pseudonym, used in literature.

Another (alive) mathematician writes under his real name and under a pseudonym (John B. Goode). (That person, by the way, is Bruno Poizat: it's no secret, even MathSciNet knows it.)

> What other mathematicians (say dead ones) had a pseudonym, either within their mathematical activity, or in a parallel career ?

Of course, don't count people who changed name at some moment of their life because of marriage, persecution, conversion, and so on.

---

**Edit**.
The answers and comments suggest that there are at least four categories of pseudonyms, which don't exhaust all situations.

- Professional mathematicians, who did something outside of mathematics under a pseudonym (F. Hausdorff - *Paul Mongré*, E. Temple Bell - *John Taine*),
- People doing mathematics under a pseudonym, and something else under their real name (Sophie Germain - *M. Le Blanc*, W. S. Gosset - *Student*)),
- Professional mathematicians writing mathematics under both their real name and a pseudonym (B. Poizat - *John B. Goode*),
- Collaborative pseudonyms (*Bourbaki, Blanche Descartes*)

Comment: Does Nicolas Bourbaki qualify?

Comment: Or Blanche Descartes?

Comment: I think you will find some answers at http://mathoverflow.net/users .

Comment: @darij: Indeed! I never knew Bugs Bunny had such a fondness for algebra and geometry.

Comment: Does Arthur Besse count?

Comment: Along the lines of Bourbaki, there's also Jet Nestruev.

Comment: Donald Knuth used the pseudonym Ursula N. Owens when submitting a paper to get more honest reviews. (As described by Wilf on page 3 of http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/website/dek.pdf)

Comment: and if i recall correctly, Ursula N. Owens comes from UNO, as in 'one' (i guess), and uno seems to be his user-name: http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/

Comment: The question's got four votes to close, yet there are no comments on why it should be closed! I'd like to cast a virtual reopening vote to offset one of the closing votes. Please, discuss on meta. 

Comment: Meta thread: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/758/pseudonyms-of-famous-mathematicians/#Item_1

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Pseudonymous_mathematicians

Comment: @Suvrit: Apparently, Ursula N. Owens is a variation on Agatha Christie's U.N. Owen: http://www.cs.oberlin.edu/~asharp/cs365/handouts/knuth.pdf

Comment: In view of recent contributions, the list seems too long already. 
Thus I am contributing a vote as 'no longer relevant'. If somebody would like to continue on this subject an option could be to ask a more narrow question based on input got via this general one.

Comment: @quid, I was coming very close to your point of view, but I believe the most recent post about Albert Gifi shows that this thread still has some life in it. 

Comment: By the way, I just learn that Fejér's original name was Weiss. He changed it at the age of about 20, to make it sound more hungarian. Fejér is approximately a translation of Weiss (= white).

Comment: When some young mathematicians were talking about an older mathematician, they were using an abbreviation of his name (in a warm, sympathetic and respectful way). Would it count here as a pseudonym?

Answer (score 113):

Monsieur Antoine Auguste Le Blanc. (Sophie Germain, 1776–1831)

Sophie Germain hid behind the male pseudonym "M. Le Blanc" to study at the École Polytechnique and to be taken seriously in mail correspondence with other mathematicians, including Lagrange and Gauss.

Answer (score 86):

William Sealy Gosset published a result under the pseudonym 
[Student](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution).
(Because his employer, the Guinness brewing company, did not allow their employees to publish for fear of divulging trade secrets.)

Comment: Wow, I did not know that Student was not a last name.

Comment: Gosset published lots of papers under that same pseudonym.  But that one early paper explains the terms "Student's distribution", "Student's t", "Studentized residual", "Studentized range" and probably some others.

Comment: The book "The Lady Tasting Tea" by David Salsburg explains: "Gosset wanted to publish this result in an appropriate journal. The Poisson distribution (or the formula for it) had been known for over 100 years, and attempts had been made in the past to find examples of it in real life ... in his yeast cell counts, Gosset had a clear example, along with an important application of the new idea of statistical distributions." (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd)  "However, it was against company policy to allow publications by its employees. A few years before, a master brewer from Guinness had written an article in which he revealed the secret components of one of their brewing processes. To avoid the further loss of such valuable company property, Guinness had forbidden its employees from publishing ... In 1906, Gosset convinced his employers that the new mathematical ideas were useful for a beer company and took a one-year leave of absence to study under (Karl) Pearson at the Galton Biometrical Laboratory." (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd)  "Two years before this, when Gosset described his results dealing with yeast, Pearson was eager to print it in his journal. They decided to publish the article using a pseudonym. This first discovery of Gosset's was published by an author identified only as 'Student.'" (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) "...There is an apocryphal story that the first time the Guinness family heard of this work occurred when Gosset died suddenly of a heart attack in 1937 and his mathematical friends approached the Guinness company to help pay the costs of printing his collected papers in a single volume. Whether this is true or not, it is clear from the memoirs of the American statistician Harold Hotelling ... that arrangements were made to meet him secretly, with all the aspects of a spy mystery. This suggests that the true identity of 'Student' was still a secret from the Guinness company."

Answer (score 62):

Felix Hausdorff published philosophical and literary books as Paul Mongré.

Let me mention that Hausdorff committed suicide (along with his wife) in 1942, to prevent his being sent to a concentration camp. He had tried to escape to the US, but unfortunately no one would sponsor him. So he joined the ranks of mathematicians who were victims of World War II (including some Germans who died at Soviet hands, for example Gentzen).

Comment: In a sense, Gentzen's fate was opposite to Hausdorff's, though: he was a supporter of the Nazi regime. A pity, either way.

Comment: How can you compare the hangman and his victim? You do an inversion? It is not this way it works in real life.

:-(

Comment: Felix Hausdorff, his wife, and his wife's sister,  committed suicide on 26 January 1942. In a letter to his friend Hans Wolstein, Hausdorff wrote about his suicide plan--Hausdorff parting words about the situation of Jews in the then Germany were: *What has happened in recent months against the Jews evokes justified fear that they will not let us live to see a more bearable situation.* ------ (See wikipedia, *Felix Hausdorff*).

Comment: @Yuval Filmus--Felix Hausdorff was not a victim of the US emigration process but because as a Jew he was persecuted by the Germany of 1930s.

Comment: @Greg Graviton--No, Hausdorff was NOT a supporter of Nazis (please, use pronouns responsibly). It seems that Gentzen was; Gentzen was a member of Nazi parties and organizations. I hope that Gentzen was only trapped by History, that he was not actively any monster. Except for Genzen's Nazi memberships (as repulsive as they were) I didn't read anything damaging about Gentzen.

Answer (score 50):

Rainich=Rabinowitsch (of  trick fame :  cf. Nullstellensatz).

Here is an anecdote related by Bruce P. Palka, Editor of *American Mathematical Monthly*
in Vol.111 (2004) of that journal (page460).

Rainich was giving a lecture in which he made use of a clever trick which he had discovered. Someone in the audience indignantly interrupted him pointing out that this was the famous Rabinowitsch trick and berating Rainich for claiming to have discovered it. Without a word Rainich turned to the blackboard, picked up the chalk, and wrote

```
                    RABINOWITSCH
```

He then put down the chalk, picked up an eraser and began erasing letters. When he was done what remained was

```
                   RA IN  I CH
```

He then went on with his lecture.

**EDIT**: There is some additional information (located by  Sándor Kovács) to be found at [jstor.org/pss/4145123](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4145123). We reproduce the relevant section below:

> "Lance also contributes some new information to the saga of the elusive Mr. Rabinowitsch (see the Editor's Endnotes in the May 2004 issue): Poor Rabinowitsch, whoever he may be. The correct reference is: J. L. Rabinowitsch, "Zum Hilbertschen Nullstellensatz", Math. Ann. 102 (1930), p.520. In various places his first initial is either "A" or "S." On my trip to the library, I saw that Rainich had published in the Annalen under his own name and from Ann Arbor the previous year. Why a pseudonym?" The mystery deepens a bit in a biography of Rainich, where it's mentioned that he was born Rabinowitsch. On the same theme, Herman Roelants of Leuven, Belgium, points out that a Rabinowitsch anecdote similar to the one in the May 2004 MONTHLY is found on page 959 of the MONTHLY paper "Reminiscences of an Octagenarian Mathematican" by L. J. Mordell (November, 1971). Herman goes on to say that details concerning this source, together with references to important number-theoretic work of Rabinowitsch, can be found in the text and in a footnote on page 108 of Richard A. Mollin's book Quadratics (CRC Press, 1996).”

Comment: Dear Georges and Sandor, I have never known who Rabinowitsch was (although of course I know the trick!), and so I am very glad to have read this answer and the comments.

Best wishes,

Matt

Comment: This was a permanent name change, not a pseudonym, no?

Comment: Yes, Gerry, I think you are right

Comment: Interesting. See also this: http://www.jstor.org/stable/4145290?seq=4 (and the following page).

Comment: Dear fherzig, thank you: I think that was the page I actually meant originally!

Comment: I question if this story is true. Here is an event recalled in the 1924 Michigan Alumni magazine, reporting on hiring of Rainich on the faculty: *An interesting story is told of an experience he had while lecturing at Columbia University. Speaking upon Relativity before the faculty he quoted a number of the foremost authorities known upon the subject. One of the members of the Columbia faculty spoke up saying "That is all very well but why don't you quote what Rabinovitch has said upon this subject"  Professor Rainich was somewhat embarrassed as he replied "Well, you see, I am Rabinovitch."*

Comment: Rainich/Rabinovich/Rabinowitsch worked in mathematical physics, particularly general relativity. If he's the same person as the one who came up with the short proof of the Nullstellensatz (in 1930), it was not part of the main direction of his work.

Comment: Here is a link to the Michigan alumni magazine article that I mentioned: https://books.google.com/books?id=AxtYAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA172&lpg=PA172&dq=rainich+1924&source=bl&ots=W3LjVnhCUe&sig=ACfU3U2BmNoMmDe0JNtfHwzs1hpiFtEFIQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwia06zA8Y_jAhXBt1kKHWAyANM4ChDoATAGegQIBxAB#v=onepage&q=rainich%201924&f=false

Comment: The story appears also in http://faculty-history.dc.umich.edu/faculty/george-yuri-rainich/bio and is just copied from the Michigan alumni magazine.

Comment: In http://faculty-history.dc.umich.edu/faculty/george-yuri-rainich/memorial-0 is quoted a similar story told by Mordell from 1923 (being at talk where Rainich was criticized for not mentioning Rabinovich) related to R's work on class numbers of quadratic fields.

Comment: Rainich left the Soviet Union in 1922, was at Hopkins 1923-1926, and was at Michigan 1926-1956.  The Rabinowitsch who published a paper on the Nullstellensatz did so in 1930 and that (short) paper lists him as being in Moscow (where Rainich never had a job while in the USSR). It all makes me think the Rabinowitsch trick is not due to Rainich.

Comment: For what it is worth, the Crelle article on quadratic fields by "Rabinowitsch from Odessa" in the Mordell story is probably this one: https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN243919689_0142?tify={%22pages%22:[157],%22view%22:%22info%22}.

Comment: That work on quadratic fields was presented by G. Rabinovitch at the 1912 ICM.  See page 418 here: https://www.mathunion.org/fileadmin/ICM/Proceedings/ICM1912.1/ICM1912.1.ocr.pdf.

Comment: I am going to leave a link to the 1930 paper on the Nullstellensatz here in case I have to look it up again: https://eudml.org/doc/159393. That author is listed as J. L. Rabinowitsch. The Rainich at Michigan was George Yuri Rainich (also Yuri Germanovich Rabinovich). Why would he use middle initial L if he wrote the  Nullstellansatz paper? It makes no sense. That together with the odd geography (Rainich from Michigan was not in the USSR after leaving the country in 1922) makes me think the Rabinowitsch from the Nullstellensatz was someone nobody knows anymore.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments! I completely agree with you, and opened the question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416577 to discuss these matters further.

Answer (score 50):

G. W. Peck originally was the pseudonym of Ronald Graham, Douglas West, George B. Purdy, Paul Erdős, Fan Chung, and Daniel Kleitman. Since then G. W. Peck was the author of sixteen publications, most by Kleitman alone. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G._W._Peck.

Answer (score 48):

Isaac Newton, in his dabblings in alchemy, called himself Jehovah Sanctus Unus.  http://science.howstuffworks.com/dictionary/famous-scientists/physicists/isaac-newton3.htm

Comment: More accurately *Ieoua Sanctus Unus*, which not only means *God, unique and saint*, but is also an anagram of Isaac Newton.

Comment: @Denis: wait a second: how do you spell "Newton"? I have a couple of "u" and "s" left over...

Comment: @Thierry Zell: Isaacus Neutonus. See his entry in Vicipedia: http://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaacus_Newtonus

Comment: Thanks Willie: I guess my question should have been: "How do you spell Isaac?" :)

Comment: It was hard for Newton to hide his identity - it was always easy to recognize the lion by his paw (Bernoulli and brachistochrone) :)

Comment: I would translate ‘sanctus’ as ‘holy’, not as ‘saint’.  But ‘unus’ may have been more important to Newton, who was (secretly) a unitarian.

Answer (score 46):

Siegel published The integer solutions of the equation $y^2=ax^n+bx^{n-1}+\cdots+k$, J London Math Soc 1 (1926) 66-68, under the pseudonym, X.

Anecdotal evidence of a non-pseudonym: Once when Littlewood attended an international conference in France, a French mathematician greeted him: “So there really is a Littlewood, and it is not just a pseudonym which G.H. Hardy uses to publish his poorer papers!”

Comment: Who was the French mathematician?

Comment: Todd, I've tried, with no success, to pin this anecdote down. I'm not entirely convinced that it actually happened, that it isn't just a joke someone made up. 

Comment: I have read the exact same anecdote where it was Landau who thus greeted Littlewood. 

Comment: Krantz, Mathematical Apocrypha, p. 45: It is said that Landau thought that "Littlewood" was a pseudonym for Hardy (so that it would not seem that Hardy was writing all the papers). Landau visited Cambridge, never saw Littlewood, and returned to Gottingen convinced that his theory was correct. No citation given. See also my next comment. 

Comment: Krantz, p. 44: It is said that when Wiener first met Littlewood he exclaimed, "Oh, so you really exist. I thought that 'Littlewood' was a name that Hardy put on his weaker papers." It should be noted that there are many variations of this story, some involving Landau instead of Wiener. [Krantz then gives the version quoted in my previous comment]

Comment: "... Curiously enough, Littlewood was the more self-effacing of the two. Later on, when he visited Edmund Landau at Göttingen, that irrepresible spoiled child of mathematics said to him, «So you do exist! I thought you were merely a name used by Hardy for those papers which he didn't think were quite good enough to publish under his own name.»" -- Norbert Wiener in I am a Mathematician (page 24 of the copy I own).

Comment: Another source, C P Snow's Foreword to Hardy's A Mathematician's Apology, p. 29: "[Littlewood] was less in the centre of the academic scene. This led to jokes from European mathematicians, such as that Hardy had invented him so as to take the blame in case there turned out anything wrong with one of their theorems." 

Comment: In a similar vein, there is a joke: Why did Bourbaki stop writing textbooks? Because they discovered that Serge Lang is one person.

Answer (score 40):

Shalosh B. Ekhad, hmm, not sure if that's exactly a pseudonym but it sort of fits this discussion.

Comment: +1 ! It is borderline, but nice. According to Wikipedia: *Doron Zeilberger is known for crediting his computer "Shalosh B. Ekhad" as a co-author ("Shalosh" and "Ekhad" mean "Three" and "One" in Hebrew respectively, referring to the ATT 3B1 model)*

Answer (score 38):

Since some of those mentioned in other answers are among the living, let me also mention Victor Kac and his teacher Ernest Vinberg.   They published a joint paper *Spinors of 13-dimensional space* in *Advances in Mathematics* 30 (1978) under the rather transparent pseudonyms V. Gatti and E. Viniberghi.   As I recall, Victor said that this came about because he had applied for an exit visa from the USSR and was therefore not allowed to publish anything in the interim.

Comment: I take it "gatti" is the Italian word for "cats"?

Comment: Yes, it is indeed.

Comment: It's so god that they didn't attempt to publish their paper in a Soviet journal. Mathematical manuscripts were vanishing when the political situation was not *politically correct*.

Answer (score 32):

**Maurizio Boyarski** = Bernard Dwork. Even mathscinet knows about that. Does anyone know why Dwork published under a pseudonym?

Dwork, Bernard: *On the Boyarsky principle.* Amer. J. Math. 105 (1983)

Boyarsky, Maurizio: *p-adic gamma functions and Dwork cohomology.* Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 257 (1980)

Comment: Very amusing :)

Comment: Could be to be able to refer to his work by name without appearing too immodest? 

Comment: Apparently Dwork wrote a not very flattering review of the paper (by Morita?) which introduced p-adic gamma functions. He later realized that these functions were important and relevant to his work and somehow was embarrassed to publish his results under his own name.

Comment: @Felipe: I see; thanks for explaining!

Comment: Cynthia Dwork told me that Boyarsky was her grandmother's (Bernard Dwork's mother) maiden name.  She published a joint paper with her father in cryptography where he once again used the name Maurizio Boyarsky.


Comment: Here's a link to the paper http://eprint.iacr.org/1999/021

Comment: With the last name Boyarsky explained, is there also an explanation of the first name?

Comment: Interesting. The grant that he acknowledges in that paper sounds fictitious. He didn't make up his affiliation though.

Comment: @Keith Conrad: This may be 2 years late, but, Bernard Dwork's middle name was Morris, which is reasonably rendered into Italian (Dwork loved Italy, and even went to live there after being retired from Princeton) as Maurizio.

Comment: Based on the titles of those papers, it sounds like maybe he wanted to name things after himself?

Answer (score 31):

[D. H. J. Polymath](https://arxiv.org/find/all/1/all%3A+polymath/0/1/0/all/0/1) is a pseudonym for a collective of mathematicians (some of them may be not professional mathematicians).

Answer (score 30):

Noga Alon published half a dozen papers under the name "A. Nilli".  Mathscinet links directly from this pseudonym to Noga's publications.

Comment: I've heard (please correct me if you know better) that the A. Nilli papers have results that he wanted to disseminate, but didn't want attached to the excellent "Alon" brand name. If that's the case, I am uncertain about the ethicality of Mathscinet outing him.

Comment: I don't think Noga was very serious about keeping it a secret, since he provided the photo of his daughter Nilli for *Proofs from the Book*. Nilli has the distinction of writing her first paper at the age of five 
(http://theoryofcomputing.org/articles/v001a009/about.html). 

Comment: Indeed, I just took a look at "A. Nilli's" first paper from 1988, and her mailing address is given as "A. Nilli c/o N. Alon, Dept. of Math, Tel Aviv University".  She also thanks N. Alon in the acknowledgments for helping her to write the paper :)

Answer (score 29):

A. Weil published two short papers/letters signed as X.X.X (Amer. J. Math. 79, 1957, 951-952) and R. Lipschitz (Ann. of Math. 69, 1959, 247-251) where he posed as an anonymous correspondent and the XIX century German mathematician residing in Hades respectively. Both letters are reprinted at the very end of the second volume of Weil's Collected papers.

Comment: André Weil was the author of the first article of Nicolas Bourbaki. Bourbaki N.: Sur un théoreme de Carathéodory et la mesure dans les espaces topologiques. C. R. Acad. sci. Paris 201 (1935), 1309-1311. Zbl 0013.15503 

Answer (score 26):

The history of **[John Rainwater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Rainwater)** can be read at the following link: http://at.yorku.ca/t/o/p/d/47.htm ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20191110102201/http://at.yorku.ca/t/o/p/d/47.htm)) He has 10 published articles and several unpublished ones, by varying authors from the University of Washington. The same page also mentions in passing three other mathematical pseudonyms: P. Orno, M. G. Stanley, and H. C. Enoses.

> John Rainwater came into existence at the University of Washington in 1952 when Nick Massey, a mathematics graduate student in Prof. Maynard Arsove's beginning real variables class, erroneously received a blank registration card. (In those years, each student filled out a card for every class, which first circulated among various tabulating clerks in the registrar's office before being sent to the professor.) He and a fellow graduate student, Sam Saunders, decided to use the card to enroll a fictional student, and since it was raining at the time, decided to call him "John Rainwater". They handed in John Rainwater's homework regularly, so it wasn't until after the first midterm exam that Prof. Arsove became aware of the deception. He took it well, even when he later opened an "exploding" fountain pen with John Rainwater's name engraved on it which had been left on the classroom table.

[...]

> The first of John Rainwater's ten published research papers were written in 1958 and 1959 by John Isbell, a young Assistant Professor. Isbell's response to queries concerning his motivation for using J.R. as a pseudonym has been simply to quote Friedrich Schiller "Der Mensch ist nur da ganz Mensch, wo er spielt."

Comment: I was trying to remember the name of this example and couldn't; thanks!

Comment: At the University of Washington, we've just donated the Collected Works of John Rainwater to the Mathematics Department Research Library, nicely leather bound. The pdf file will be publicly available soon, including Bob Phelp's four page description of Rainwater's life and work, part of which is excerpted above.

Comment: @DouglasLind, is the PDF available?

Comment: @Lspice Haven't got it posted yet, but I can send you the PDF if you like. You can find my email at the University of Washington Math Department website.

Answer (score 23):

Heisuke Hironaka published a result on complex analysis in one variable (see Remmert's "Classical topics in complex function theory", chapter 5) in 1965 under the name Iss'sa. Apparently the name is a reference to a Japanese poet.

Comment: Ah! That's one of my favorite results in complex analysis.

Comment: From "The Mathematical Work of Heisuke Hironaka" http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~prims/pdf/44-2/44-2-8.pdf :

Under the pseudonym of Hej Iss’sa (Kobayashi Issa is a famous Japanese poet) Hironaka settled in 1966 (see H. Iss’sa, On the meromorphic function field of a Stein variety, Ann. of Math. (2) 83 (1966), 34–46) a long standing problem in the theory of Riemann surfaces.

The story that I heard (which might be very garbled) is that Hironaka sent this in under a pseudonym, and the editor then picked Hironaka as a referee!


Comment: Steve Shatz told me that HH told him that the material of the Iss'sa paper was not consistent with the unity and thrust of his other work.

Comment: I am truly curious, why *Issa*?

Comment: I've searched up Iss'sa's theorem many times, after reading it in Remmert's book. I never knew it was a pseudonym--just thought it a weird name.

Answer (score 23):

At the height of fascist persecution of Jews, Federigo Enriques penned some of his articles as Adriano Giovannini (reputedly coined from the names of his daughter Adriana and of his son Giovanni), as a device to circulate them. I was able to trace back to that pseudonym at least two papers: "Il pensiero di Galileo Galilei" and "L'errore nelle matematiche". 
As I understand it, that is to be considered a pseudonym used just in publications rather than a fully new name for real life, so I deemed the answer qualifying with regard to the question requirements.

Also, not being able to comment others' answers, I can add von Neumann as good example of the category depicted in Andreas' answer.

Answer (score 21):

Arthur L. Besse - after the round tables held at Besse in France. (The "L." is for Lancelot.)

**Edit**

From Wikipedia, [Arthur Besse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Besse) is a pseudonym chosen by a group of French differential geometers, led by Marcel Berger, following the model of Nicolas Bourbaki. A number of monographs have appeared under the name.

Comment: And who are the people forming Arthur Besse?

Comment: According to the preface of  "Einstein manifolds" [Ergebnisse der Mathematik und ihrer Grenzgebiete. 3. Folge, Bd. 10. Berlin etc.: Springer (1987; <a href="https://zbmath.org/0613.53001">Zbl 0613.53001</A>): Marcel Berger, Hermann Karcher, Jean-Pierre Bourguignon, Geneviève Averous, Nigel Hitchin, Jerry Kazdan, Pierre Pansu, Paul Gauduchon, Dennis DeTurck, Lionel Bérard-Bergery, Andrei Derdzinski, Josette Houillot, Norihito Koiso, Albert Polombo, John A. Thorpe, Jacques Lafontaine, Liane Valère.

Answer (score 21):

The paper "Why You Cannot Even Hope to Use Gröbner Bases in Public-Key Cryptography? An Open Letter to a Scientist Who Failed and a Challenge to Those Who Have Not Yet Failed" by Boo Barkee ,  Julia Ecks ,  Theo Moriarty ,  R. F. Ree: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.5.7134

The lead author is Moss Sweedler.  Boo Barkee was the name of his dog (so does this count as a pseudonym :-)?).

Comment: That would depend on how much the dog contributed to the paper. 

Comment: According to Moss "Boo Barkee revealed his love for mathematics
when he licked a draft of the paper about SAGBI.
(From “Subalgebra Analog to Gr¨obner Bases for Ideals”)"

Comment: Moss told me that in searching for appropriate titles for papers written by Boo Barkee, he thought the best was "Marking trees in characteristic $p$".

Answer (score 19):

**[E. S. Pondiczery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E._S._Pondiczery)** was a pseudonym used by [R. P. Boas, Jr.](https://genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=6870) in the paper *Power problems in abstract spaces*. The name became part of the well-known [Hewitt-Marczewski-Pondiczery](http://at.yorku.ca/t/o/p/c/40.htm) theorem ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20200207055655/http://at.yorku.ca/t/o/p/c/40.htm)).

Another pseudonym used by Boas (and [F. Smithies](https://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=18538)) was **H. Pétard**. I highly recommend that you take a look at the hilarious *Lion hunting and other mathematical pursuits (A collection of mathematics, verse, and stories by the late Ralph P. Boas, Jr.)* for more information in this regard.

**Added** (Nov 7/2010)**.** In that book you can also learn about other pseudonyms (for instance, Ian Stewart's one) and the memorable feud 'twixt Bourbaki and Boas.

**Added** (Nov 8/2010)**.** According to page 10 of the aforementioned book, H. Pétard was in fact a pseudonym that Boas and Smithies made up for the use of E. S. Pondiczery.

Comment: H. Petard married Bourbaki's daughter Betti, right? And Blanche Descartes (I mentioned her/them above) wrote Hymne to Hymen on that occasion... Ah, the Poldevians.

Comment: If my memory serves me well, you cand find the invitation to their wedding in the aforementioned recollection of stories.

Comment: It might be in the book, I found out about it from this post: http://www.neverendingbooks.org/index.php/the-wedding-invitation-that-nearly-killed-andre-weil.html

Comment: @HarunŠiljak The link is broken, [this is a working alternative (for now)](http://www.neverendingbooks.org/the-wedding-invitation-that-nearly-killed-andre-weil).

Answer (score 19):

I'm surprised that no one named Leonardo of Pisa, known as *Fibonacci* to us (though he didn't use this nickname, and its origin is not completely clear).

*Al-Khoresmi* is apparently a nickname as well (though this time used by the author), meaning his origin.

(Maybe not exactly an answer to the original question, because these are rather nicknames, not pseudonyms.)

Comment: I think that Leonardo da Pisa is the nickname (whose meaning is clear), while Fibonacci is his family name, being the contraction of "filius bonacci"="son of Bonacci". 

Comment: If you mean by Al-Khoresmi "Abu Ja'far Muhammad ibn Musa Al-Khwarizmi"
then I think he does not qualify. It was customary at the time to use geographic names of family origin as family name. This means that he had the name "Al-Khwarizmi" all his life and that his father, brothers and sons (if he had any) had the same name. 

Comment: Few sidenotes:
1. Bearing the name Abu Jafar implies that he most probably had a son named Jafar.
2. drawing a line between first and family name in Oriental naming schemes is quite hard - so one can consider 'al-Khwarizmi' as just a part of his family name.
3. My experience tells me that most of people with 'geographic' family names get those when they move - i.e. I believe Al-Khwarizmi is not an exception in that case - family probably got the name when they moved to the south.

This is a bit off-topic, but I couldn't help it.

Comment: It was common in the early middle ages to identify people by their first name and home town, hence names like Leonardo of Pisa. In his time, the transition to using family names as we do today was under way. Fibonacci means "of the Bonacci family," not "son of Bonacci." (His father's name with Guglielmo). He also used the name Bigollo, which was truly a nickname.

Answer (score 17):

Eric Temple Bell (known for Bell numbers, series, polynomials, as well as his book Men of mathematics) wrote sci-fi novels using pseudonym John Taine.

Comment: Some consider the book you named as a work of sci-fi as well (or at least bi-fi).

Answer (score 16):

When it became dangerous for **Jacques Feldbau** to publish under this own (Jewish) name, he briefly wrote under the name **Jacques Laboureur** before being captured by the Nazis.  See Weil's *Souvenir d'apprentissage* or the commetaries in his *Collected papers*.  See also [*Une histoire de Jacques Feldbau*](http://www-irma.u-strasbg.fr/~maudin/feldbau-pro.pdf) by Michèle Audin, her [article](http://images.math.cnrs.fr/Plaques-commemoratives.html) in the *Images des Mathématiques* and Jean Cerf's [article](http://smf4.emath.fr/Publications/Gazette/1995/64/smf_gazette_64_23-28.pdf) ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20061119055844/https://smf.emath.fr/Publications/Gazette/1995/64/smf_gazette_64_23-28.pdf)) in the *Gazette*.

Answer (score 15):

Henri-Paul de Saint Gervais is a collective pseudonym of fifteen mathematicians
who recently published a book, *Uniformisation des surfaces de Riemann, retour sur un
théorème centenaire*, about the uniformization of Riemann surfaces.
([presentation of the book](http://www.ens-lyon.eu/1296724979770/0/fiche_article), in French).
They met in Saint-Gervais to work on the book, hence the lastname.
The firstname, Henri-Paul, reminds of Henri Poincaré and Paul Koebe, of course!
By the way, this book is highly recommended !

Comment: The above link is broken, but prepublication versions of the book itself may be found on Ghys's website: http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/ghys/articles/Uniformisationsurfaces.pdf (FR), http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/ghys/articles/Uniformization-proofs.pdf (EN)

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure whether to count as pseudonyms the altered names that people took (often to avoid antisemitic prejudice) as replacements for their real names.  For example, Alfred Tarski's last name was originally Tajtelbaum, and Edward Marczewski's last name was originally Szpilrajn.  There must be lots of other examples of this sort.

Comment: Denis explicitly asked us not to count people who changed their name(s) because of persecution. I'm not sure why. Perhaps it is to make a distinction between a permanent, official change of name and a temporary use of a pseudonym while keeping (or intending to return to) one's original name. If those are the rules, maybe Feldbau would count (see Chandan's answer), but not Tarski. Or maybe Denis would like to clarify. 

Comment: Imre Lakatos, who wasn't strictly speaking a mathematician, but not very far, was born Avrum Lipsitz. He changed definitely his name for a clear reason. I count him as a mathematician since his thesis "Proofs and Refutations" had a big influence on me, to help me understand the process of doing mathematics.

Comment: Along the lines of altered names: D'Alembert was abandoned and adopted when he was an infant. But neither his birth parents nor his adoptive parents were named D'Alembert. He made up the name when he was a college student.

Comment: An anecdote (I hope that it's true :-) *** After WWII, during his lecture in Wrocław (Poland), Marczewski mentioned one of his old results. A Rusian visitor in the audience had objected: *this is a Szpilrajn's theorem*. The other older Polish mathematicians tried to explain that Szpilrajn and Marczewski is one and the same person. The visitor still disagreed: *No way! Szpilrajn was murdered by Germans during WWII. Szpilrajn was a STRONG mathematician.*

Answer (score 13):

"Smooth Manifolds and Observables" by
Jet Nestruev.

The actual team of
Authors: A. M. Astashev, A. V. Bocharov, S. V. Duzhin, A. B. Sossinsky, A. M. Vinogradov, M. M. Vinogradov

Springer-Verlag, Graduate Texts in Mathematics, vol. 220, 2002

A Russian answer to Bourbaki (see the preface to the book).

Comment: "Nestruev" loosely means "Non-streaming" in Russian, by the way... That is, we have a "non-streaming stream" for the name.

Answer (score 12):

MR 23 #A2744 reads,

Schark, I. J.

Maximal ideals in an algebra of bounded analytic functions.

“I. J. Schark” is a pseudonym for the group: Irving Kaplansky, John Wermer, Shizuo Kakutani, R. Creighton Buck, Halsey Royden, Andrew Gleason, Richard Arens and Kenneth Hoffman. J. Math. Mech. 10 1961

Comment: Clickable link:  [MR 23 #A2744](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=125442).

Answer (score 11):

- **Thomas Young** (of diffraction, elasticity, and Rosetta Stone fame) published mathematics as

  1. [**Emeritus**](http://www.archive.org/stream/catalogueofscien06royarich#page/471)
  2. [**Hydrophilus**](http://www.archive.org/stream/catalogueofscien06royarich#page/471)
  3. [**Apsophus**](http://www.archive.org/stream/catalogueofscien06royarich#page/471)
  4. [**Dytiscus**](http://www.archive.org/stream/catalogueofscien06royarich#page/471)
  5. [**Hemerobius**](http://www.archive.org/stream/catalogueofscien06royarich#page/471)
  6. [**A. B. C. D.**](http://www.archive.org/stream/catalogueofscien06royarich#page/471)
  7. [**E. F. G. H.**](http://www.archive.org/stream/catalogueofscien06royarich#page/471)
  8. [**S. B. L.**](http://www.archive.org/stream/catalogueofscien06royarich#page/471)
- **Norbert Wiener** published [The Miracle of the Broom Closet](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?697405) and [The Brain](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?95019) as **W. Norbert**.
- **James Joseph Sylvester** (itself an [adopted surname](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Sylvester.html)) published [papers](http://www.archive.org/stream/catalogueofscien03royarich#page/830) as [**Lanavicensis**](https://www.google.com/search?filter=0&q="Lanavicensis").
- **Michel Rolle** (d’Ambert) was [**Remi Lochell** (de Bertam)](https://books.google.com/books?id=cVE-AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA470&dq=Lochell) in polemics against the calculus.
- **William Roberts** published several papers as [**M. Strebor**](//archive.org/details/catalogueofscien05royarich/page/850).
- **Joseph Liouville** was his own alleged correspondent [**M. Besge**](http://minidml.mathdoc.fr/cgi-bin/minidml?ats=Besge) (Neuenschwander, [p. 60](https://ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=87h:01045)).
- **Pascual Jordan** (of quantum mechanics, Jordan algebras fame) expressed “extreme far-right political views” under the pseudonym [**Ernst Domeier**](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Jordan_Pascual.html).

Comment: !!! This is wonderful. How did you get hold of it?

Comment: [This other question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/310523/early-examples-of-mathematicians-publishing-from-home-in-a-foreign-language) made me look at Young’s linked bibliography.

Answer (score 10):

[André Bloch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr%C3%A9_Bloch_(mathematician)) was an active mathematician during his stay (1918-1948) in a psychiatric asylum. During WWII, he wrote under the pseudos *René Binaud* and *Marcel Segond*, to hide his Jewish name.

Answer (score 10):

Joseph Bernstein published a paper under the pseudonym "Yantarov" (which is derived from the Russian
translation of the German word "Bernstein" which means "amber").
At the time of writing he was an "otkaznik", a person waiting for permission to emigrate from the USSR,
and a paper under his own name would not be accepted.

Comment: Dennis Serre gave the Bloch example on 18 June. 

Comment: There is an actress named Amber Bernstein, http://www.imdb.com/name/nm8661914/ – I wonder whether her parents knew they were naming her Amber Amber.

Answer (score 9):

In the 1980's there were a few papers by Bill Moran, William G. Hoover and Stronzo Bestiale; the most famous is http://williamhoover.info/Scans1980s/1987-3.pdf
If you read italian, it will be obvious for you that there is something wrong with the last name. There is a legend that the first two authors were so upset about the third co-author, that they replaced his true name with this one: see http://web.archive.org/web/20091026050929/http://individual.utoronto.ca/scharf/bizarre.htm.
The paper went through the whole refereeing and publishing process!

Comment: Si non è vero, è bene trovatto !

Comment: That second link seems to have died. 

Comment: Try

http://web.archive.org/web/20091026050929/http://individual.utoronto.ca/scharf/bizarre.htm

Comment: See https://www.parolacce.org/2014/10/05/the-true-story-of-stronzo-bestiale/

Answer (score 9):

From *Zinbiel, G.W.*, [**Encyclopedia of types of algebras 2010**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1142/9789814365123_0011), Bai, Chengming (ed.) et al., Operads and universal algebra. Proceedings of the summer school and international conference, Tianjin, China, July 5--9, 2010. Hackensack, NJ: World Scientific (ISBN 978-981-4365-11-6/hbk; 978-981-4458-33-7/ebook). Nankai Series in Pure, Applied Mathematics and Theoretical Physics 9, 217-297 (2012). [ZBL1351.17001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1351.17001).:

"Note that J.-L. Loday published this article under the pseudonym Guillaume William Zinbiel (Zinbiel is Leibniz written backwards)."

Comment: On the home page of Jean-Louis Loday one may find [Biographie de G. W. Zinbiel](http://irma.math.unistra.fr/~loday/Zinbiel.html)

Answer (score 8):

D. P. Parent is the author of a book of *Exercises in Number Theory*. 
Its authors are D. Barsky, F. Bertrandias, G. Christol, A. Decomps, H. Delange, J.-M. Deshouillers, K. Gérardin, J. Lagrange, J.-L. Nicolas, M. Pathiaux, G. Rauzy and M. Waldschmidt.
The initials of the pseudonym recall the names of Delange, Pisot and Poitou,
the three organizers of a Number Theory Seminar in Paris, which runs since 1959.

Answer (score 7):

It might be a stretch but Ben Franklin spent time on recreational mathematics https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square, [https://www.amazon.com/Benjamin-Franklins-Numbers-Mathematical-Odyssey/dp/0691129568/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691129568), and called himself a number of pseudonyms (Richard Saunders, Mrs. Silence Dogood) in his other writings.

Answer (score 7):

Hugo Steinhaus was also an author of aphorisms, which he published in the daily "Slowo Polskie" under a pseudonym Sestertius.  Most were just goofy definitions of everyday terms. The following example seems to do OK in translation from Polish: "An opinion that all high-rank officers are stupid: a generalization".  The book edition ("Slownik Racjonalny") appeared in 1980 (after his death) under his real name.

Answer (score 7):

D'Alembert's name was in a sense a "pseudonym." D'Alembert was abandoned as an infant. However, d'Alembert was neither the name of his birth parents nor his adoptive parents. He made it up when he was a student.

Comment: Yes, you mentioned this on 31 March 2011 in a comment on a post of 7 November 2010 by Andreas Blass, earlier in this discussion. 

Answer (score 7):

Albert Gifi is a  group pseudonym for a groupf of authors writing "Nonlinear Multivariate Analysis" From this Wikipedia page:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jan_de_Leeuw

"De Leeuw is the originator[4] of the Albert Gifi team that wrote Nonlinear Multivariate Analysis.[5] In Multidimensional Scaling, Volume 1,[6] Cox and Cox write that "Albert Gifi is the nom de plume of members, past and present, of the Department of Data Theory at the University of Leiden who devised a system of nonlinear multivariate analysis that extends various techniques, such as principal components analysis and canonical correlation analysis."   "

Answer (score 7):

Boto von Querenburg wrote a book on general topology, which is one of the standard source in German. According to Wikipedia the name actually stands for the authors Gunter Bengel, Hans-Dieter Coldewey, Klaus Funcke, Edelgard Gramberg, Norbert Peczynski, Andreas Stieglitz, Elmar Vogt and Heiner Zieschang. The name Boto was chosen as an abbreviation of "Bochum topologists" and the University of Bochum is in a part of the town called Querenburg.

Answer (score 7):

[Elena Ventzel](https://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/author.html?mrauthid=198874) is not a very famous mathematician, although her textbook on Probability for engineers was (still is?) by far the most famous and widely used one in Russia.

She had a successful separate career as a fiction writer under a pen-name I. Grekova (derived from "igrek").

Answer (score 7):

For reasons that it amuses him not to explain, Harold Simmons published the book [First Steps in Modal Logic](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/first-steps-in-modal-logic/8522B4DD9F5069D41B896B2D9666D2DD) under the pseudonym *Sally Popkorn*.

Answer (score 6):

**O. P. Lossers** has published since 1965, mostly problem solutions in various journals.  He has Erdös number 2.

Comment: I dunno about this one. There are many problem solvers out there that submit stuff pseudonymously. For instance, several years ago, it was commonplace to see the pen name ALFRED E. NEUMAN in the problem department of the Pi Mu Epsilon Journal.

Comment: Some more information on O.P.Lossers (apparantly, he was even asked to referee!) can be found on
Wim Nuij's website (http://www.win.tue.nl/~wsinwaan/)
His name just spells "solvers" in Dutch btw.


Comment: See also http://cameroncounts.wordpress.com/2013/07/24/partitions-into-petersens/#comment-11951 where Peter Cameron also explains (and confirms) the pseudonym.

Answer (score 6):

**T. G. L. Zetters**, has proven in 1979 that either player can draw in the 8-in-a-row game.  This is a variant of the well known 5-in-a-row where players take turn placing their mark to a square on an infinite square grid, and a player wins if they have a consecutive sequence of 8 or more of his own marks in a row, column, or diagonal.  According to the book Csákány Béla, *Diszkrét Matematikai Játékok* (Polygon, Szeged, 1998), this is a pseudonim of a group of Dutch mathematicians.  According to the manuscript András Csernenszky, The Chooser-Picker 7-in-a-row-game (submitted in 2010, arXiv:1004.2460v1), it is a pseudonym for A. Brouwer.

Comment: A. Brouwer actually lists this article as one of his on his webpage (http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/publications.html).
If you speak out the name, it just says "tilers" in Dutch.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to being the "G" of G. W. Peck (as pointed out by Richard Stanley earlier), Ron Graham also published "On properties of a well-known graph or What is your Ramsey number?" as Tom Odda, a member of the Department of Mathematics from Xanadu University.

Apparently the name was chosen because if said quickly it sounded like the Chinese expression 他妈的 pronounced "ta ma de", a not so polite phrase in Chinese!

Comment: There's a very strange thing about the review of that paper in Math Reviews: it refers to itself. It says, "see also MR0557896 (81d:05055)," when in fact it is MR0557896 (81d:05055). How did that happen? 

Answer (score 6):

One may type "pseudonym" into an "Anywhere" box at MathSciNet and find 44 hits. Many of these are not relevant to the question at hand, but I'll post any that I find that haven't been posted here already. Here's one: Christian Tapp, Kardinalitat und Kardinale, MR 2006h:01012, the review by Volker Peckhaus says that in Chapter 5, "We learn about [Georg] Cantor's pseudonyms such as Vincent Regnas, Jorge Vincente Monteador de Montemor, and others...."

Answer (score 6):

Continuing to troll through MathSciNet, I find Yu I Krivonosov, Higher mathematics and higher authority, MR 2002k:01034, reviewed by R L Cooke (and I highly recommend the review). It seems that A I Lapin, a convicted anti-Soviet agitator, confined to an asylum in Leningrad, was allowed to publish under a pseudonym in 1952.

Comment: According to S. S. Demidov, Vopr. Istor. Estestvozn. Tekh. 2001, No. 2, 122--126 (2001; Zbl 0996.01013), the pseudonym used was A. I. Ivanov.

Answer (score 6):

Yet another find on MathSciNet. Anita Feferman, Politics, Logic, and Love, MR 93j:01010, reviewed by D J Struik. This is a biography of Jean van Heijenoort. "In 1948 he broke openly with his past in a paper of [sic] the Partisan Review, where he denied the scientific nature of Marxism. He wrote it under a pseudonym (Jean Vannier) - after all he was an alien and it was the McCarthy period."

Answer (score 6):

Here's one more from MathSciNet. N Ya Vilenkin, Formulas on cardboard, MR 93a:01039, reviewed by B Rosenfeld. Nikolay S Koshlyakov was arrested in 1942, was denounced as an "enemy of the nation," and was condemned to ten years in the camps. The book written by him in the camp, Investigations of a class of transcendental functions determined by the generalized equation of Riemann, was published ... in 1949 ... under the pseudonym N S Sergeev (Koshlyakov's patronymic name was Sergeevich).

Answer (score 6):

The mathematician [Dan Barbilian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dan_Barbilian) was also a poet, having the pen name Ion Barbu. Some of his works are described [here](http://www.mathem.pub.ro/bjga/v1n1/B01-IO.PDF) ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20130511092755/http://www.mathem.pub.ro/bjga/v1n1/B01-IO.PDF)) and [here](http://www.gbv.de/dms/goettingen/19783275X.pdf) ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20161018165955/http://www.gbv.de/dms/goettingen/19783275X.pdf)).

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, Horst Herrlich has some publications as Y.T. Rhineghost.
http://www.informatik.uni-bremen.de/~herrlich/public/index.html ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20121113194607/http://www.informatik.uni-bremen.de/~herrlich/public/index.html))
http://www.csupomona.edu/~hlord/geist/ ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20110607014623/http://www.csupomona.edu/~hlord/geist/))

I do not know the story behind this pseudonym.

Comment: Y.T. Rhineghost has a great homepage: http://www.csupomona.edu/~hlord/geist/

Comment: According to that homepage Rhineghost was a group five people. Rhineghost wrote 58 reviews for math.sci.net - some of them about articles of his own members, see numbers 11 and 22 on the list of reviews

Comment: The above link seems to be dead. Here is [link to Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/%2A/http://www.csupomona.edu/~hlord/geist/) and specifically to the [last working capture](http://web.archive.org/web/20110927005555/http://www.csupomona.edu/~hlord/geist/).

Answer (score 6):

Jacob Goodman published the as-yet-unsolved Pancake Problem under the pseudonym, Harry Dweighter ("harried waiter"). See, e.g., https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~west/openp/pancake.html

Answer (score 6):

P. A. Batnik was a pseudonym used by Paul T. Bateman and Bruce Reznick for contributions to the American Math Monthly's problems column. See, e.g., http://celebratio.org/Bateman_PT/article/332/

Answer (score 6):

[Gergonne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Diez_Gergonne) has published 43 additional papers anonymously or under a pseudonym in his Annales des Mathématiques pure et appliquée (1810–1831). In his copy of the journal given to the Sorbonne library, he had added his name manually to these contributions (see *Henry, C.*, Supplément à la bibliographie de Gergonne., Bonc. Bull. 14, 211-218 (1881). [JFM 13.0019.01](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:13.0019.01).).

Answer (score 6):

Peter Cameron tells the story of the collaborative pseudonym WE Opencomb in his (Peter’s) blog

https://cameroncounts.wordpress.com/2009/10/28/collaboration-in-mathematics/

Answer (score 5):

Heinrich Seidel's review of M Lothaire, Combinatorics on Words, MR 84g:05002, says "The name of the author is a pseudonym chosen by the mathematicians who together with D Perrin serve as coauthors." There are about a dozen coauthors.

Comment: Yes, this was detailed in the preface to the 2nd edition of their first book (Combinatorics on Words). It stands for Lothaire aka Lothar I, King of Lotharingia. The similarities to the Bourbaki name choice are interesting...

Comment: It turns out that there is a "Séminaire Lotharingien de Combinatoire" (Lotharingic seminar of combinatorics), to which some of my colleagues of the University of Lyon are associated. This must not be a coincidence. The denomination comes from the fact that Lotharingie was the kingdom between France and Germany (approximately from the North See to the Mediteranean See) after Verdun's treaty in 843. It did not last, because France and Germany fought to dominate it. This fight lasted more than a thousand years, till 1945. 

Comment: Clickable link:  [MR 84g:05002](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=675953).

Answer (score 5):

I guess, though I am not sure, the case of [Albert Wormstein](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/448078/83875) falls in your third category:

Professional mathematicians writing mathematics under both their real name and a pseudonym.

[This paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/0097-3165(92)90058-3): "Polyominoes of order 3 do not exist" (Journal of Combinatorial Theory, Series A, Volume 61, Issue 1, September 1992, Pages 130–136) has been written by I. N. Stewart and A. Wormstein.

Here is the story behind the paper as told by Ian Stewart himself.

> [The link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/448078/83875) has the correct story. Albert Wormstein first appeared in one of my articles for Pour La Science /
>   Scientific American, which was used as a chapter in the cited book. 
>   While I was writing that article it suddenly seemed clear that there
>   ought to be a way to prove the conjecture about order 3 polyominoes.
>   It felt as though Albert was tapping me on the shoulder and saying
>   'come on, we can do this.' It quickly turned out he was right. So I
>   decided to give him credit as a co-author. The journal either spotted
>   the joke and went along with it, or they assumed Albert was a PhD
>   student. At any rate, they published it with him as co-author.

Comment: MathSciNet list AW as an author, though with only this paper, and does not identify him with INS.

Answer (score 5):

I realize now that *Oscar Zariski* was only a variation of his original name **Ascher Zaritsky**. He changed his name when publishing his dissertation, perhaps to hide his Jewish origin in the fascist Italy.

Comment: "Of course, don't count people who changed name at some moment of their life because of marriage, persecution, conversion, and so on."  Not a pseudonym.

Answer (score 5):

A very common type of pseudonym, especially in the Renaissance, was a Latinisation. Examples include:

- *René Descartes* becomes *Renatus Cartesius*;
- *Mikołaj Kopernik* becomes *Nicolaus Copernicus*;
- *Geert de Kremer* becomes *Gerardus Mercator*;
- *Willebrord Snel van Royen* ('Snell') becomes *Willebrord Snellius*.

(Mathematics was not as well-established as a single profession at the time, and most of the people listed were active in many fields of science. A true Renaissance scientist is a polymath.)

**Remark.** For some reason, this practice seems to have been especially popular in the Low Countries. This is somewhat remarkable, given that (following Simon Stevin, another Renaissance scientist) the Dutch language dropped Latin and Greek loanwords like *subtract*, *multiply*, and even *mathematics* itself, in favour of the Dutch words *aftrekken*, *vermenigvuldigen*, and *wiskunde*. There are very few European languages that have their own word for *mathematics*.

**Remark.** One may argue that a Latinisation does not constitute a pseudonym, but if we translate *pseudonym* literally as *false name*, then any name deviating from a person's actual [legal] name can be considered a pseudonym.

Comment: I think the notion of actual/legal name may post-date some of these people...

Comment: "Any name deviating from a person's actual [legal] name can be considered a pseudonym" is setting the bar rather low.  The French tend to spell my last name as "Israël", while Americans tend to render my first name as "Bob".  I don't think those would be pseudonyms.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: I can see your point, although I would have found it slightly more convincing if the person her/himself modifies the name, rather than other people misspelling or misidentifying it. This of course also happens a lot: there are a lot of Bobs out there whose legal name is Robert.

Comment: I think that calling these pseudonyms is anachronistic -- it is more likely that this was the standard kind of name one adopted for purposes of scholarly discussion or reputation-building

Comment: I have come to agree with the comments: the point of a pseudonym is traditionally to *hide* (or at least obscure) your identity, so linguistic variations don't really count...

Answer (score 5):

According to the review of  Reinhard Siegmund-Schultze, *Sørensen, Henrik Kragh*, [**Louis Olivier: a mathematician only known through his publications in Crelle’s journal during the 1820s**](https://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1600-0498.2006.00046.x), Centaurus 48, No. 3, 201-231 (2006). [ZBL1115.01012](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1115.01012)., "ventures several hypotheses, including that ‘[Olivier](https://zbmath.org/authors/?q=ai:olivier.louis)’ was a pseudonym. From the information revealed in this article the reviewer is inclined not even to rule out that Olivier and Crelle were the same person."

Answer (score 5):

[Pytheas N. Fogg](https://zbmath.org/authors/?q=ai:pytheas-fogg.n) is a collective of several authors including Valérie Berthé, Sébastien Ferenczi, Christian Mauduit, Anne Siegel and others - Review of J. P. Allouche of

*Pytheas Fogg, N. (ed.); Berthé, Valérie (ed.); Ferenczi, Sébastien (ed.); Mauduit, Christian (ed.); Siegel, A. (ed.)*, [**Substitutions in dynamics, arithmetics and combinatorics**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/b13861), Lecture Notes in Mathematics. 1794. Berlin: Springer. xv, 402 p. EUR 57.95/net; sFr. 96.50; £ 40.50; $ 76.80 (2002). [ZBL1014.11015](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1014.11015).: "This collective book, published under the pseudonym N. Pytheas Fogg, based on courses given by the authors in several universities and during several summer schools".

Answer (score 4):

Another find on MathSciNet. Dominique Descotes, *Genese des corollaires 1 et 2 de la lettre à Carcavy de Blaise Pascal*, MR 99g:01016, review by Craig Fraser: In December of 1658 Blaise Pascal began to publish under the pseudonym A Dettonville the mathematical work Lettres de A Dettonville.... According to C B Boyer, "the name Amos Dettonville was an anagram of Louis de Montalte, the pseudonym used [by Pascal] in the Lettres provinciales."

Answer (score 4):

According to Daniel Lazard, in his review of Berenstein and Struppa, Recent improvements in the complexity of the effective nullstellensatz, MR 92m:13024, N Fitchas was a pseudonym for a working group led by J Heintz that got results on the membership problem and the representation problem.

Answer (score 4):

Volume 1 of Statistical Methods of Model Building, edited by Helga Bunke and Olaf Bunke, was first published under the pseudonym of K M S Humak. See the review by J Kleffe, MR 88d:62121. See also MR 86b:62002.

Comment: Clickable links:  [MR 88d:62121](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=843076) and [MR 86b:62002](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=724604).

Answer (score 4):

The review by E Reich of I J Good and K Caj Doog, A paradox concerning rate of information, MR 19, 1245h, informs us that "The name of the second author is understood to be a pseudonym."

Comment: From [Jack Good](//www.theguardian.com/science/2009/apr/29/jack-good-codebreaker-obituary), *Good Thinking* ([1983](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=85j:62003), pp. [321, 281, 35, 24](//books.google.com/books?id=zPZgDwAAQBAJ&q=Doog|Tibetan)): “Good’s alter ego”, “introduced as a joint author to justify the use of “we” in a publication.” “Doog is the guy who spells everything backwards.” “In the spoken version of this paper I named my position after “the Tibetan Lama K. Caj Doog,” and I called my position “Doogian” (...) “Bayesian” is misleading, and “Goodian” or “Good” is absurd.”

Comment: Clickable link:  [MR 19, 1245h](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=93439).

Answer (score 4):

Although some think of Pythagoras as one person, it is now thought that his name is used for geometric and number theoretical discoveries made by anonymous members of his sect.

Thus, we can think of "Pythagoras" as the pseudonym of a collective of Greek intellectuals from about 500 BCE.

Comment: Do you have any reference for that? This seems a bit authoritarive statement.

Comment: What about "Pythagoras and the Early Pythagoreans" by Leonid Zhmu, page 257? You can see that page in google books. The fact that all his sect's discoveries were attributed to Pythagoras is common knowledge, although I could not get another explicit reference in the 10 minutes I spent finding the above.

Comment: sounds like what happens nowadays for discoveries in a typical medical lab...

Answer (score 4):

"[Madame Veuve Prime/Madame F. Prime](https://zbmath.org/authors/?q=ai:prime.f)" was most likely a pseudonym (see *Eneström, G.*, Questions 41 48. Remark on the question 43, Bibl. Math. (2) VII. 31-32, 64, 96, 120 (1893); (2) VIII. 32, 63-64, 96, 120 (1894) (1893,1894). [ZBL25.0011.05](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:25.0011.05).), but so far no one seems to have identified the author.

Comment: Most of Madame Veuve F.Prime's papers seem to have been published in Journal de Mathématiques Elémentaires between 1892 and 1895. While the name does sound like a pseudonym, I doubt it was a famous mathematician, more probably a high school teacher or a student. In a 1892 article she is mentionning Brussels as her hometown (but this could be a decoy), see https://archive.org/stream/s4journaldemathm01pari#page/162/mode/2up/search/prime In any case, it does indeed appear to be difficult to identify the author.

Answer (score 3):

Niccolò Fontana best known as Tartaglia.

Comment: But was that actually a pseudonym?

Comment: Tartaglia is more a (pejorative) nickname than a pseudonym I think. If I were him, I wouldn't like people on the street calling out "Hey, there's Niccolo the Stammerer!"

Comment: Is it worse than the French translation "Hé, voilà Henri Lebesgue" ?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [K.M.S. Humak](https://zbmath.org/authors/?q=ai:k-m-s-humak.) mentioned earlier (which encodes "Kollektiv Mathematische Statistik: Humboldt-Universität zu Berlin und Akademie der Wissenschaften der DDR"), Helga Bunke had a long-term career in literature under her maiden name [Helga Königsdorf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helga_K%C3%B6nigsdorf).

Answer (score 3):

*Andersen, Kirsti; Meyer, Henrik*, [**Georg Mohr’s three books and the Gegenübung auf Compendium Euclidis Curiosi**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1600-0498.1985.tb00833.x), Centaurus 28, 139-144 (1985). [ZBL0571.01014](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0571.01014). discusses the identity of J.D.S., author of "Gegenübung auf Compendium Euclidis Curiosi (1673)", and are convinced that it is *not* (as assumed by Bierens de Haan) a pseudonym of Georg Mohr (hence, the real identity seems still open).

Answer (score 3):

[Gohierre de Longchamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaston_Albert_Gohierre_de_Longchamps) used the pseudonym *Elgé* for publications in *Journal de mathématiques élémentaires* and *Journal de mathématiques spéciales* of which he was editor, see

*Lazzeri, G.*, Gastone Gohierre de Longchamps, Periodico di Mat. (3) 4, 53-59 (1906). [ZBL37.0031.04](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:37.0031.04).

Answer (score 3):

"Mathematician" might be a slight stretch, but math-related and of real-world significance: no one has yet figured out who Satoshi Nakamoto is.

Answer (score 3):

Křesomysl Blizzard https://zbmath.org/authors/blizzard.kresomysl was a pseudonym of the collective of Walter Schachermayer, Erik G. F. Thomas and Heinrich von Weizsäcker for the publication

*Blizzard, Křesomysl*, [**A Krein-Milman set without the integral representation property.**](https://dml.cz/handle/10338.dmlcz/701173), Frolík, Zdeněk (ed.), Abstracta. 8th winter school on abstract analysis. Abstracts of papers presented at the winter school, WSAA 8, Moravská Bouda, Czech Republic, 1980. Prague: Czechoslovak Academy of Sciences. 39-42 (1980). [ZBL1437.46007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1437.46007).

Note that the DML CZ https://dml.cz/handle/10338.dmlcz/701173 did only partially resolve the identity as E.G.F. Thomas with the remark "Author corrected, K. Blizzard did not participated at the school"; the full identity is given in [20] of Schachermeyer's homepage [https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~schachermayer/pubs/index.php](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Eschachermayer/pubs/index.php).

Answer (score 2):

Does Plato count?  (No pun entirely intended.)

Comment: I don't follow.

Comment: @Qiaochu Some consider him not only a philosopher but also a mathematician.  And the nickname "Plato" has become so standard that probably most people don't recall what his actual name was.

Comment: @Michael, his real name being ...?

Comment: _Aristocles_ according to Wikipedia's article about him.  I don't know if I knew that, but I've been familiar with the nickname meaning "broad-shouldered" or something like that for a long time.

Comment: Who considers Plato a mathematician, and on what grounds?

Comment: @Gerry: One person who considers Plato a mathematician put the assertion into the first paragraph of the Wikipedia article about him.  It's in more than one place in the article and maybe more than one person put it there.  You can look at the edit history, and maybe even find out the actual identities of those who did that.  My uncertainty about the "grounds" you asked about was why I phrased my answer as a question.

Answer (score 2):

Noaï Fitchas was a pseudonym for the group of Joos Heintz and his students Leandro Caniglia, Guillermo Cortiñas, Silvia Danón, Teresa Krick, and Pablo Solernó.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that here on 9 November 2010. 

Comment: I thought I carefully checked that it had not been mentioned earlier... Sorry for my mistake!

Answer (score 2):

Endre Weiszfeld, a childhood friend of Erdős, changed his name to Andrew Vázsonyi to escape persecution as a Jew. But much later, he also used the alias Zepartzatt Gozinto, at least for [this book review](https://www.jstor.org/stable/167604). The story goes that the name arose when he made a joke in a talk and George Dantzig misheard it.

Answer (score 1):

[Levi Ben Gershon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gersonides) (1288-1344) (see also [here](http://web.stonehill.edu/compsci/Shai_papers/MathofLevi.pdf)) is commonly known to us as the RaLBa"G. Again, this is a nickname rather than a pseudonym- RLBG = "Rabbi Levi Ben Gershon", much in the same way as Shah Rikh Khan is known as SRK.

He wrote three mathematics books including Maaseh Hoshev, which "... is notable for its early use of proof by mathematical induction, and pioneering work in combinatorics. "

Comment: An abbreviation is not a pseudonym.  He wrote his works under his real name;  RaLBa"G is how others refer to him, but did he ever use that?

Comment: He may have written his works under the Latinization of his name, Gersonides.

Comment: Is the quote mark in RaLBa"G literally a quote mark, or some sort of diacritic?

Comment: @LSpice The quotation mark "gershayim" indicates an acronym. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershayim