# Question on a relation between minors of a particular kind of matrix

Tags: determinants, linear-algebra

Hi!

Perhaps it is an easy question but i don't figure out how to prove it.
Let $a_1,...,a_{2m+2}\in\mathbb{C}$ and for $1\leq i\leq 2m+2$ and $j\leq [\frac{2m+2-i}{2}]$ (with $[a]$ i mean the integer part of $a$) consider the matrix $A(i,j)=(a_{i+k+l})_{0\leq k,l\leq j}$. I denote with $D(i,j)=\det(A(i,j))$. I have to prove the following relation:$$D(1,m-1)D(3,m-1)-D(1,m)D(3,m-2)=D(2,m-1)^2$$

I tried by induction but i didn't manage to get the result.

Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: First : did you try in low dimension, to get a feel of the problem.

Second : is it homework you want done?

Comment: @Snark: yes i tried in low dimension and the result is correct, i didn't find this relation as an exercise or homework but in an article i'm reading. It is said "well known identity on determinants" so i tried to prove it because i didn't know that identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This must be a consequence od the Dodgson's condensation formula. See Exercise 24 on my web  [site](http://www.umpa.ens-lyon.fr/~serre/DPF/exobis.pdf). By the way, C. L. Dodgson was the real name of Lewis Caroll (see the MO question [link text](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45185).