# minimum-maximum entries matrix

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, matrices, determinants, matrix-inverse

Let $M(n)$ be an $n\times n$ matrix in the variables $x_1,\dots,x_n$ with entries
$$M_{i,j}(n)=\frac{x_{\max(i,j)}}{x_{\min(i,j)}}, \qquad 1\leq i,j\leq n.$$
I'm interested in the following:

> **Questions.**
>
> (1) Is there a neat or "closed form" evaluation for the determinant $\det M(n)$?
>
> (2) Is there an explicit formula for the inverse of $M(n)$?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let us write $$a_r=\frac{x_{r+1}}{x_r}$$ for $r=1\cdots n$.

We can then write the matrix $M(n)$ in the form 
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & a_1 & a_1a_2& \cdots & a_1a_2\cdots a_{n-1} \\ a_1 & 1 & a_2& \cdots & a_2\cdots a_{n-1}\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\ddots & \vdots\\ a_1a_2\cdots a_{n-1}& a_2\cdots a_{n-1} &\cdots & a_{n-1} & 1\end{pmatrix} $$ 
We do now Gauss elimination, and reduce $a_{n-1}$ times the $(n-1)$-th row from the $n$-th row. We then get in the last row $0, 0, \ldots (1-a_{n-1}^2)$.
But this means that $det(M(n))=det(M(n-1))(1-a_{n-1}^2)$ and by induction
$$det(M(n)) = \prod_{r=1}^{n-1} (1-a_r^2)=\prod_{r=1}^{n-1}(1-\frac{x_{r+1}^2}{x_r^2}).$$
By using inductively the Gauss elimination mentioned above, one can also get the inverse of $M(n)$.

Comment: Thanks. What is the inverse, explicitly?

Comment: Nice. The last product should also contain squares, right?

Comment: I didn't do the exact calculations for the inverse matrix. What I can say is the following: 
We can use Cramer's Rule. Then all the $n-1\times n-1$ minors will either have zero determinant, or will be something of the form $a_i \cdot M(n-1)$ for some $i$ (and $M(n-1)$ stands here for some reordering of the indices). You will then get quite an explicit formula.

Comment: I understand, it makes sense. But, I anticipate a neat answer for the inverse - just like the determinant.

Comment: Regarding $a_i$ as an indeterminate in the matrix of Ehud's answer, the matrix is the Varchenko matrix of the arrangement of $n-1$ parallel lines in the plane. See for instance Section 6.5 of http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis610/sp06stanley.pdf. Theorem 6.25 of this reference therefore gives a vast generalization of $\det M(n)$. The inverse of $M(n)$ is a tridiagonal matrix with terms $a_i/(a_i^2-1)$ on the diagonal above and below the main diagonal, and with $(1,1)$-entry $1/(1-a_1^2)$, $(n,n)$-entry $1/(1-a_{n-1}^2)$, and other diagonal entries $(1-a_i^2a_{i+1}^2)/(1-a_i^2)(1-a_{i+1}^2)$.

Comment: Solving (2) for $M^{-1}$ (thanks to Stanley) actually gives away (1) more readily, because computing the determinant the tridiagonal $M^{-1}$ is much easier (thus we get $\det M$ immediately).

Comment: A slick way to evaluate Ehud's matrix is notice that two rows become equal if we set $a_i=1$ and become negatives if we set $a_i=-1$. A simple degree argument shows that there are no other factors, and setting each $a_i=0$ gives the correct scaling factor (i.e., the polynomial has constant term 1).

Answer (score 3):

I wish to advertise the [Method of Condensation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodgson_condensation) in proving determinantal evaluation. The **key** is guess the answer, which is thanks to Ehud Meir. Then, generalize it a bit. Let $x_1, x_2,\dots$ be an infinite set of variables and modify the original matrix (by shifting variables) to $M^{a,b}(n)$ so that
$$M_{i,j}^{a,b}(n):=\frac{x_{\max(i+a,j+b)}}{x_{\min(i+a,j+b)}}.$$
*Convention:* $M^{0,0}(n)=M(n)$.

**Claim.** If $a\neq b$ then $\det M^{a,b}(n)=0$, and if $a=b$ then
$$\det M^{a,a}(n)=\prod_{r=2}^n\frac{x_{k-1+a}^2-x_{k+a}^2}{x_{k-1+a}^2}.\tag1$$
**Proof.** The case $a\neq b$ is easy - simply factor out a variable from $n^{th}$-column/row and another variable from the $(n-1)^{th}$-column/row. These new columns/rows are identical.

Inductive proofs neatly work with this Dodgson's recursive relation
$$\det Z^{0,0}(n)=\frac{\det Z^{1,1}(n-1)\det Z^{1,1}(n-1)-\det Z^{0,1}(n-1)\det Z^{1,0}(n-1)}{\det Z^{1,1}(n-2)}$$
satisfied by any matrix (so long as denominators do not vanish). Thus, it holds for $\det M^{a,b}(n)$.
So, it remains to prove that the (explicit) formula on the RHS of (1) *does* satisfy the same equation. However, this is quite a routine simplification (preferably with symbolic sofwares). The proof follows. $\square$

Comment: Incidentally, Charles L. Dodgson was better known as Lewis Carroll. See the MO question http://mathoverflow.net/q/45185 .

Comment: Yes, I was aware: https://www.math.temple.edu/~tewodros/papersps/RABBIT.PDF