# Reference request - localisation de g-modules

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, paper-request

Does anyone have a link to a copy of Beilinson-Bernstein's "Localisation de g-modules", in which they prove the Beilinson-Bernstein theorem? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Where have you looked?  The short paper was published in *C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris Sér. I Math.* 292 (1981), no. 1, 15–18.   I'm not sure what can be found online, but the paper itself has been widely used over the years.   

Comment: I've got an English translation I TeXed for myself.  Not sure if I am "supposed" to distribute it, though.

Comment: No worries, I can read French!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6226873r/f29](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark%3A/12148/bpt6k6226873r/f29)

Comment: Thanks! I've just tried to find it directly through their webpage but it seems that instead of Series I they have Series II. Youw link works even after 6 years.