# Most squares in the first half-interval

Tags: analytic-number-theory, nt.number-theory, reference-request

It is well known that if $p$ is an odd prime, exactly one half of the numbers $1, \dots, p-1$ are squares in $\mathbb{F}_p$. What is less obvious is that among these $(p-1)/2$ squares, at least one half lie in the interval $[1, (p-1)/2]$.

I remember reading this fact many years ago on a very popular book in number theory, where it was claimed that this is an easy consequence of a more sophisticated formula of analytic number theory.

Sadly I forgot both the formula and the book. So the purpose of the question is double:

> 1) Has any simple way been found to derive the fact mentioned above?
>
> 2) Does anybody know a reference for the analytic number theory route to the proof?

Comment: Note that this is trivial for $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ because then $-1$ is a quadratic residue, and any $k$ is a quadratic residue if and only if $p-k$ is. So exactly half lie in your interval, exactly half lie in the interval from $(p+1)/2$ to $p-1.$

Comment: Another reference: "Introduction to Cyclotomic Fields", L. C. Washington, pp 45, exercise 4.5.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nope!  Amazingly enough, no elementary proof of this fact is yet known (Edit:  See KConrad's answer).  The difficulty is tied up in some pretty fantastic algebraic/analytic number theory, namely the analytic class number formula.  But, without getting into that, here's the short form of the story: let $L(s)$ be the $L$-function attached to the character arising from the Kronecker symbol mod $q$.  Then one can compute analytically via the Euler product formula for this $L$-function that (for an explicit positive constant $C$), 
$$
L(1)=C\left[\sum_{m=0}^{q/2}\left(\frac{m}{q}\right)-\sum_{m=q/2}^{q}\left(\frac{m}{q}\right)\right]=\frac{\pi}{\left(2-\left(\frac{2}{q}\right)\right)q^{1/2}}\sum_{m=0}^{q/2}\left(\frac{m}{q}\right),
$$
the positivity of which gives the desired statement about the distribution of quadratic residues.

For a reference (from whence I pulled this out of), Davenport's "Multiplicative Number Theory" is pretty fantastic.  This is all done in the first 4-5 pages.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not the book I had in mind, but it is fine nevertheless.

Answer (score 29):

There is a method of explaining this without using analytic methods.  I will get to that at the end of this answer.

First, if $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ then this result is clear since -1 is a square mod $p$.  So here exactly half the squares mod $p$ lie in the first half of $[1,p-1]$.  The real problem is for $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$, where analytic methods show there are *more* squares mod $p$ lying in the first half of that interval than in the second half because there is a formula for the class number of ${\mathbf Q}(\sqrt{-p})$  that is 1 or 1/3 times $S - N$, where $S$ is the number of squares mod $p$ in $[1,(p-1)/2]$ and $N$ is the number of nonsquares mod $p$ in $[1,(p-1)/2]$. Class numbers are positive integers, so $S > N$, which means in $[1,(p-1)/2]$ the squares mod $p$ outnumber nonsquares mod $p$. Since there are as many squares as nonsquares mod $p$ on $[1,p-1]$, the square vs. nonsquare bias on the first half of this interval forces there to be more squares mod $p$ on the first half than squares mod $p$ on the second half.

For a proof by analytic methods, see Borevich-Shafarevich's "Number Theory", Theorem 4 on p. 346.  It is *not* true that no non-analytic derivations of this bias are known.  For instance, Borevich and Shafarevich say on p. 347 that Venkov gave a non-analytic proof for some cases in 1928 (which came out in German in 1931: see Math Z. Vol. 33, 350--374). I should clarify this point since there is a bad typo in Borevich and Shafarevich here. What Venkov did was give a non-analytic proof of Dirichlet's class number formula for imaginary quadratic fields having discriminant $D \not\equiv 1 \bmod 8$.  Here the book unfortunately has $D \equiv 1 \bmod 8$. (It's clear from the book that something is wrong because shortly after saying Venkov treated $D \equiv 1 \bmod 8$ by non-analytic methods they say the case $D \equiv 1 \bmod 8$ still awaits a non-analytic proof.) The class number formula only gets an interpretation about squares or nonsquares for the fields ${\mathbf Q}(\sqrt{-p})$, but Venkov was working on non-analytic proofs of the class number formula for imaginary quadratic fields without having this restrictive case as the only one in mind. R. W. Davis (Crelle 286/287 (1976), 369--379) made simplifications to Venkov's argument.

What cases for ${\mathbf Q}(\sqrt{-p})$ are covered by Venkov? When $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$, the discriminant of ${\mathbf Q}(\sqrt{-p})$ is $-p$. If $p \equiv 3 \bmod 8$ then $-p \equiv 5 \bmod 8$, while if $p \equiv 7 \bmod 8$ then $-p \equiv 1 \bmod 8$, so Venkov had non-analytically proved the formula when $p \equiv 3 \bmod 8$.  The case $p \equiv 7 \bmod 8$ remained open.

In 1978 the *whole problem was solved*.  Davis, in a second paper (Crelle 299/300 (1978), 247--255), handled some but not all cases of imaginary quadratic fields with discriminant $1 \bmod 8$ (corresponding to $p \equiv 7 \bmod 8$ for the fields ${\mathbf Q}(\sqrt{-p})$) by non-analytic methods and in the same year H. L. S. Orde settled everything by non-analytic methods.  See his paper "On Dirichlet's class number formula", J. London Math. Soc. 18 (1978), 409--420.

Comment: Very helpful answer, thank you! In Russian 3rd edition of Borevich and Shafarevich, last paragraph on p. 383, Venkov's reference is OK (no typo).

Comment: Very informative!  +1

Comment: У меня нет копии русского варианта. Опечатка в первом русском изданием? Английский перевод появился в 1966 г., а второе русское издание вышло в 1972 г. (см. lib.mexmat.ru/books/4065) 

Comment: (For others: I'm asking whether the first Russian edition of B/S has  the typo, since only the first Russian edition was out when it was translated.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your references! I will check them out.

Comment: Andrea, back copies of Crelle can be found online at 
http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/no_cache/dms/load/toc/?IDDOC=238618



Comment: Have you had a look at the review(s) of Orde's paper in Math Reviews? The original review said the proof followed Dirichlet, was more analytic than arithmetic, and that Venkov (or Wenkov) had already given an elementary and purely arithmetic proof. Then A I Vinogradov wrote an addendum to the review refuting these points. 

How often does one see an addendum in Math Reviews? 

Comment: When I looked at Math Reviews (which I did to get the bibliographic information in my response above), what I saw first was the updated version by Vinogradov.  The contrast to the original review is pretty striking!

Comment: Very nice answer.  By coincidence, I received a copy of B&S in the mail today.  I've been referred to this book on and off for about 10 years without being able to get my hands on a copy...Finally, things will be different and I will henceforth understand number theory.  (Just kidding.  Maybe.)  

Comment: Pete:  One unusual thing is that B&S develop factorization theory using Krull rings instead of Dedekind domains (but they call them "rings with a theory of divisors"). In particular, when they show the integral closure of a Krull ring in a finite extension of its fraction field is a Krull ring, as Theorem 1 on p. 193, they need no separability hypothesis (or a reduction to separable and inseparable cases). I was surprised when I read other alg. num. thy. books later: nearly all make separability hypotheses for extensions of Dedekind domains and don't at least *say* that it's not essential.

Comment: Keith Matthews showed me a copy of the original (Russian) 1st edition of Borevich-Shafarevich from 1964 and its reference to Venkov does not have the typographical error from the English translation that I wrote about in my answer above.