# Can the integration of integrable sections of a measurable function of two variables ever result in a non-measurable function?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, integration, counterexamples

I spent some time searching MathOverflow for a problem that would resemble the one given below, but it turned out to be a rather futile endeavor. I was led to this problem in my attempts to construct a counterexample refuting a result that had already been published in a peer-reviewed article.

> **Problem.** Find measure spaces $ (X,\mathcal{S},\mu) $ and
>     $ (Y,\mathcal{T},\nu) $, at least one of which is *not* $ \sigma $-finite, and
>     an $ (\mathcal{S} \otimes \mathcal{T}) $-measurable function
>     $ f: X \times Y \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} $ with the following properties:
>
> - The function $ f(x,\bullet): Y \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} $ belongs to
>     $ {L^{1}}(Y,\mathcal{T},\nu) $ for every $ x \in X $.
> - The function
>     $ \left\{ \begin{matrix}
>       X & \to     & \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \\
>       x & \mapsto & \displaystyle \int_{Y} f(x,\bullet) ~ \mathrm{d}{\nu}
>       \end{matrix} \right\}
>     $
>     is *not* $ \mathcal{S} $-measurable.

Does anyone know if this problem can even be solved? Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Doesn't seem like the measure $\mu$ is even used here.

Comment: A short note to anyone studying this problem: In accordance with Daniel’s comment, one may let $ \mu $ be the trivial measure on $ (X,\mathcal{S}) $, which makes $ (X,\mathcal{S},\mu) $ a $ \sigma $-finite measure space. Therefore, in order for a counterexample to exist, it is necessary that $ (Y,\mathcal{T},\nu) $ be non-$ \sigma $-finite, otherwise the second function in my post would be $ \mathcal{S} $-measurable (as can be seen by analyzing any standard proof of the Fubini-Tonelli Theorem).

Comment: Another short note: PhoemueX has provided a nice counterexample below that satisfies the second property, but it is unclear whether or not it also satisfies the first property. A brief analysis of PhoemueX’s argument leads one to the following question: Does there exist a Borel subset $ M $ of $ \mathbb{R}^{2} $ such that (i) each vertical cross-section of $ M $ is finite, i.e., $ \{ y \in \mathbb{R} \mid (x,y) \in M \} $ is finite for each $ x \in \mathbb{R} $, and (ii) the projection of $ M $ onto the first coordinate is a non-Borel analytic subset of $ \mathbb{R} $?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{B}$ denote the class of Borel subsets of $[0,1]$ and let $A \subseteq [0, 1]$ be a non Borel set. Let $f$ be the characteristic function of the graph of a bijection from $A$ to $[0, 1]$. Then $f$ is $\mathcal{B} \otimes \mathcal{P}([0, 1])$-measurable (check) and the map $x \mapsto \int f(x, y) d\mu(y)$ is non-zero precisely on $A$ where $\mu$ is counting measure.

**Edit:** I was asked to provide more details so here they are.

Suppose $W \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is such that every horizontal section $W^y = \{x : (x, y) \in W\}$ is closed. Then $W \in \mathcal{B} \otimes \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$. To see this, define, for each interval $J$ with rational endpoints, $Y_J = \{y : W^y \cap J = \phi\}$. As each $W^y$ is closed, we have
$$
W = \mathbb{R}^2 \Big\backslash \bigcup \{J \times Y_J : J \text{ is an interval with rational endpoints}\} \in \mathcal{B} \otimes \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}).
$$
It follows that the graph of every partial bijection on $\mathbb{R}$ is in $\mathcal{B} \otimes \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$.

Now choose any non Borel set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and an injection $i: A \to \mathbb{R}$. Define $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ to be the characteristic function of the graph of $i$. Let $\mu$ be the counting measure on $\mathbb{R}$. The map $x \mapsto \int f(x, y) d\mu(y)$ is precisely the characteristic function of $A$ and hence is non-Borel.

Comment: Hi rumpf. Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, I don’t consider myself to be smart enough to check your claim in the third line. Could you elaborate further?

Comment: For each rational interval $J$, let $Y_J$ be the set of points where the horizontal section of the graph of the bijection is disjoint with $J$. Now consider the union of $J \times Y_J$'s.

Comment: I am getting confused by these definitions; I think it would help if more things had names.  Let's call $\phi : A \to [0,1]$ the desired bijection.  It looks to me like you want $Y_J = \phi(A \cap J^c)$?  That doesn't seem to make sense.  In particular if $y = \phi(x)$ then $(x,y)$ is not in $J \times Y_J$ for any $J$.

Comment: @Nate: drumpf’s improved argument does appear to check out. What do you think?

Comment: @Transcendental: Yes, I think so too.  +1 from me.  Maybe a simpler way of describing $f$ is that it is just $f(x,y) = 1$ iff $x=y \in A$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: @Nate: It also appears that his argument works if we let $ X $ be any uncountable second-countable $ T_{1} $ topological space whose Borel $ \sigma $-algebra $ \mathcal{S} $ isn’t all of $ \mathcal{P}(X) $ (i.e., $ X $ has a non-Borel subset). Any uncountable standard Borel space automatically satisfies this property (assuming the Axiom of Choice, of course).

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT**: The following only provides a *partial* answer, since it is not clear at all that the first property of the question ($f(x, \cdot) \in L^1(Y, \mathcal{T}, \nu)$) is fulfilled for the given example.

---

Let $(X, \mathcal{S})$ and $(Y, \mathcal{T})$ both be the real line with the Borel sigma algebra. Note that the product sigma algebra is again the Borel sigma algebra (but on $\Bbb{R}^2$).

It is well-known (see [Projection of Borel set from $R^2$ to $R^1$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34142/projection-of-borel-set-from-r2-to-r1)) that not every projection of a Borel set is a Borel set. Hence, let $M \subset \Bbb{R}^2$ be a Borel set such that the projection $\pi_1 (M)$ is not Borel measurable.

Let $\mu$ be the counting measure on the real line. If
$$
F(x) := \int_{\Bbb{R}} 1_M (x,y) d \mu(y)
$$
was measurable, then so would be the set
$$
\pi_1 (M) = \{x \,:\, \exists y : (x,y) \in M\} = \{x \,:\, F(x) > 0\}.
$$

Comment: Wikipedia claims that Fubini always works for the "maximal product measure." I wonder what that means if the iterated integrals aren't even defined. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Failure_of_Fubini.27s_theorem_for_non-maximal_product_measures

Comment: @PhoemueX: Thanks! I must shamefully admit that the fact you quoted wasn’t known to me.

Comment: @Christian: Fubini’s Theorem states that if $ (X,\mathcal{S},\mu) $ and $ (Y,\mathcal{T},\nu) $ are measure spaces, and if $ f \in {L^{1}}(X \times Y,\mathcal{S} \otimes \mathcal{T},(\mu \otimes \nu)_{\text{max}}) $, where $ (\mu \otimes \nu)_{\text{max}} $ denotes the maximal product measure, then the iterated integrals exist and are equal to $ \displaystyle \int_{X \times Y} f ~ \mathrm{d}{(\mu \otimes \nu)_{\text{max}}} $. I suspect that the function $ \mathbf{1}_{M} $ defined by PhoemueX above isn’t integrable on $ \mathbb{R}^{2} $ with respect to the maximal product measure.

Comment: @PhoemueX: Your counterexample clearly satisfies the second property, but can you show that it also satisfies the first property? In other words, can you prove that $ \{ y \in \mathbb{R} \mid (x,y) \in M \} $ is finite for each $ x \in \mathbb{R} $? Thanks!

Comment: @Transcendental: Yes, I realized this problem just this morning.  With the current construction, I don't think this is true. I will delete my answer if I see no way to fix it until this evening :(

Comment: @PhoemueX: Please don’t delete your answer as I (and many other people) considered it very helpful. Even if you aren’t able to find a fix in the end, somebody else might. :)

Comment: @Transcendental: Ok, sure :) I just thought it would draw more attention to the question, since at the moment it seems to be answered. I will just edit it to show more clearly that it is not a complete answer.

Comment: To make one more unhelpful remark, the fact that $M$ is Borel in $\mathbb R^2$ is actually not that relevant perhaps since one could have taken $\mathcal P(Y)$ as the $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$.

Comment: @Christian: It’s clear that $ M $ is a member of the $ \sigma $-algebra $ \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}) $, but any act of whittling down each vertical cross-section of $ M $ to make it finite might threaten this membership.

Comment: As discussed [here](http://mathoverflow.net/a/253740/4832), the Lusin-Novikov theorem says that your example *cannot* satisfy the first property.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Nice, that looks fascinating. I always wanted to learn more about descriptive set theory :)