Has the mathematics research community ever been led astray by a dumb mistake?
This is a highly subjective question, but here goes.
Has anyone ever published a result that was "taken seriously" by the research community, but was then discovered to be incorrect because of a "dumb mistake"?
Allow me to (somewhat) clarify my terms:

By a "dumb mistake", I mean "any mistake that is immediately obvious to any professional on the community upon being pointed out". Another requirement for the mistake to count as "dumb" is that there be nothing "mathematically interesting" or educational about it. Examples would include arithmetic errors, errors of elementary algebra, accidentally using one formula in place of another intended one, transcribing an equation incorrectly, or "obvious" bugs in computer code. In order to count, the mistake should be able to be described very succinctly. I would say that "a failure to make an 'easy' conceptual leap" would generally not count, although I acknowledge that all of this is pretty subjective.

"Taken seriously" is definitely pretty ambiguous, but I would say that the result "made a splash" in the research community. Sufficient evidence to demonstrate this could be, say, the paper making the incorrect claim receiving a large number of citations, or a significant number of subsequent papers relying on the claim, or a statement by a "major figure" in the field listing a major open problem that follows from the claim, etc. It doesn't count if the mistake was almost immediately pointed out by someone else (although what counts as "almost immediately" is also ambiguous). Basically, the rough threshold that I'm wondering about is that the mistake "did some nontrivial damage to the research process by leading subsequent researchers astray for a time", even it was ultimately corrected.


I'm not really looking for a paper that made a big controversial claim, and most experts assumed that it was probably wrong but took a little while to find the mistake. I'm more looking for a paper that was broadly accepted to be correct when it was published, and it "flew under the radar" for a bit before anyone realized that the claim was wrong.

Well, there was a Daniel Biss affair, and his "The topological fundamental group and generalized covering spaces" (cited at least 3 times in papers actually using results from it). The dumb mistake of this paper was not defining objects properly. Ambiguous usage of the term 'cover' led to a series of interesting results, all of which were corollaries of contractibility of $S^1$.

Similar question (might be too similar, in fact): https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35468

The counter-example that Wang found to Grunwald's "Theorem" is pretty simple, maybe that example qualifies?: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grunwald%E2%80%93Wang_theorem

@DenisT: According to Mnev, the mistake was quite concrete. See https://arxiv.org/abs/0709.1291 for details.

@SamHopkins I agree that my question has some overlap with that one, but I think that the focus on the mistake being "dumb" makes this question different enough to not be a duplicate.

Well, there are many mistakes that are "immediately obvious" once things are stated in adequate terms, but are possibly not that obvious to detect while reading the faulty proof.

@DenisT Some people were pointing out Bliss seemed sloppy in his definitions back when he was in grad school, but the concerns got blown off by the most senior people.

@Buzz wow. I wonder why....

@DavidRoberts Why?

@YCor Yes, of course. I'm not sure what you're getting at? I'm certainly not restricting to mistakes that should have been caught during peer review.

@tparker for what reason did senior people brush off concerns with work that turns out to have flaws all over the place? Why did they have confidence in him? Or at least profess confidence in his work despite people pointing out concerns?

@DavidRoberts: I first met Biss when he was a postdoc and I was a graduate student, so I can’t speak to what happened back in his grad school days.  But he definitely had the kind of arrogance one can only get from being treated as a genius from one’s youth.  Mathematicians have an unfortunate tendency to anoint certain kinds of prodigies as brilliant and then treat then uncritically (and conversely, to anoint other people as idiots, and then dismiss them even when they do good work).  We would do well to be way more humble about our ability to recognize talent.

Thanks, @Andy. I have to say that I cannot throw stones, because I live in a glass house and also published a paper as a PhD student, with one of my advisors, that since then needed to be retracted (the real mathematics is much more interesting, and couldn't have been done at the time...at least by me!) But I didn't go to Harvard and MIT, and my paper made an epsilon-sized impact even on my niche area of work.

Russell's paradox.

@TempusNomen Russell's paradox is certainly not an example, since it wasn't a mistaken derivation but a contradictory system of axioms, and in particular it badly fails the criterion "Another requirement for the mistake to count as "dumb" is that there be nothing "mathematically interesting" or educational about it." since it is one of the most mathematically interesting brief arguments in history.

It's not contradictory axioms. The problem assumed something that was already excluded by an axiom. Also, I myself don't find anything interesting about it.

@TempusNomen If you think this is an answer, please post it as an answer.

One should take a close look at the many "proofs" of Euclid's fifth postulate that were given in the years prior to the work of Lobachevsky and Bolyai. I think many of them were predicated on relying on self-evident facts that on closer inspection turn out to be equivalent to assuming the parallel postulate.

Yamabe's original approach to his eponymous problem was shown by Trudinger to have a serious error, which Jack Lee asserts here was a sign error.  I think that would qualify as dumb.  Yamabe's result was taken seriously (by such as Aubin).  However, a cursory examination of the papers didn't turn up a sign error, but I'm by no means an expert.  Perhaps one could comment on the nature of the error and whether it was "dumb"?

@TempusNomen Can you elaborate on what you mean by "The problem assumed something that was already excluded by an axiom"? This doesn't match my understanding of the history of Russell's paradox. But also I'm not sure what "the problem" refers to...

@dvitek It’s been a while since I studied the proof, but I don’t think Yamabe’s mistake was “dumb” at all. My recollection is that he made some crucial mistakes considering the critical exponent for the Sobolev problem, which is reasonably subtle. More importantly, his ideas played a crucial role in the eventual proof (although it required much more careful analysis), so it’s not as if his work was a dead end in any way.

Answers and comments here are overlapping with answers to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/879/most-interesting-mathematics-mistake:   Kempe's incorrect proof of the 4-color conjecture, the discovery of analytic sets, attempted proofs of Euclid's 5th postulate, Hilbert's 16th problem, the Grunwald-Wang theorem.

@KConrad That's ironic, because my question is the exact opposite of that one.

@tparker Maybe you want to add "mathematics" to "research community" both in the title and the question itself, what do you think? It should be self-explanatory since we are on mathoverflow, but some answers show that they interpreted your question without this restriction, thus being offtopic.

@MartinBrandenburg I edited the title, since it's clear that's what was meant

In 1970, Irwing Noel Baker "proved" that a transcendental entire function of one complex variable can have at most one completely invariant component of the set of normality. In fact he "proved" a more general statement that there cannot be two disjoint domains whose preimages are connected. His paper occupies three pages,
and contains an elementary mistake (a geometric statement which looks completely evident at the first glance). During the period 1970-2018, Baker's argument was used in several papers.
In 2018 I tried to explain
Baker's argument to Julien Duval, he could not  understand it, and finally he found that it is incorrect.
In the same year a counterexample to Baker's theorem
was constructed, and the original question about
completely invariant domains remains unsolved.

Well, that's a good anecdote why asking "dumb questions" when you can't follow is not just OK, in fact, it is utterly important. Thanks for sharing this story.

What was the "geometric statement which looks completely evident at the first glance"?

People in the comments have already pointed out Daniel Biss's thesis.  But he also made two other unrelated mistakes that to my mind are more interesting:

In his paper,
D. Biss & B. Farb, $\mathcal{K}_g$ is not finitely generated, Invent. Math. 163(1), 2006, 213-226.
Biss and Farb claim to prove that the so-called Johnson kernel subgroup of the mapping class group is not finitely generated.  People definitely took this seriously when it came out, and it had consequences for other kinds of finiteness results (see, for instance, the discussion in Farb's paper "Some problems on mapping class groups and moduli space").
The mistake here was that they gave an algorithm for constructing a bunch of curves on a surface and claimed that they were disjoint.  Later on, Masatoshi Sato (then a PhD student at the University of Tokyo) carefully drew pictures of these curves and verified that they were not disjoint.  The proof fell apart.  Even better, it later turned out that the Johnson kernel subgroup is finitely generated (which might have been discovered much sooner if the community was not misled by Biss-Farb's theorem).  See
M. Ershov & S. He, On finiteness properties of the Johnson filtrations, Duke Math. J. 167, 2018, 1713-1759.
and
T. Church, M. Ershov, & A. Putman, On finite generation of the Johnson filtrations, J. Eur. Math. Soc. 24, 2022, no.8, 2875-2914.

In his papers
D. Biss, A generalized approach to the fundamental group,
Amer. Math. Monthly 107 (2000), no. 8, 711-720.
and
D. Biss, The topological fundamental group and generalized covering spaces, Topology Appl. 124 (2002), no. 3, 355-371.
Biss studied the fundamental groups of spaces that do not have universal covers.  His main theorem says that there is a natural topology on these fundamental groups making them into topological groups.  This has been fairly influential, e.g. they were part of his work cited for the Morgan prize, and the second paper has 97 citations on google scholar.  However, he makes some elementary point-set topology mistakes that invalidate his proofs (totally different from the mistakes in his other papers!).  In fact, for many easy examples the purported "topological group structure" he defined is not continuous.  This was pointed out in
P. Fabel, The topological Hawaiian earring group does not embed in the inverse limit of free groups, Algebr. Geom. Topol. 5 (2005), 1585-1587.
For a very nice discussion of the history, I recommend the blog post here.



That Biss gentleman seems good at making incorrect arguments look amazing, he should try politics.

While pointing out mistakes made by people is often useful, I feel somewhat uncomfortable with the way Daniel Biss' mistakes are being collected and exposed...     (This answer does not feel like an answer to the question "Has the research community ever been led astray by a dumb mistake?". It feels to me like something else... )

@AndréHenriques: I would be uncomfortable with this in most situations.  However, this is unique for several reasons: 1. I am not aware of any other recent case where someone made so many unrelated errors that were taken seriously by so many people, and I think there is an important lesson to be learned as to how this happened; and 2. Biss is not exactly young or powerless.  Back when he was in math, he was an absolute superstar (Clay Fellow, assistant professor at UChicago, etc).  Now he is the mayor of Evanston, which is a very wealthy city in the Chicago metro area.

(I would definitely be vehemently opposed to e.g. someone using this question to draw attention to some poor random grad student who wrote an erroneous paper)

I feel compelled to mention here the only other mathematician I know who was a mayor, Frank Arnold Garside: see the discussion in the Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garside_element. (Incidentally, Garside's work has stood up, as far as I know.)

@SamHopkins Tadatoshi Akiba did some work on homotopy groups, and was mayor of Hiroshima for a long time.

It's not just on one person, the math community should prevent these errors from being published via the peer-review process, especially in journals as renowned as Invent. Math! But that process seems to be fundamentally broken, and I am happy that the recent uprise of formalized proofs offers a more neutral and professional review process. (I assume many papers are and have been approved because their results "look good", which is clearly not sufficient.) PS: I also asked about the fundamental group here.

@MartinBrandenburg: I don't think the process is "fundamentally broken".  I know that we like to tell ourselves that peer review is magic, but no process involving people excludes errors 100%.  There have been wrong proofs published throughout mathematical history, and they only hurt people who are too lazy to carefully read the literature they are citing.  I am very skeptical of any claimed solutions, e.g. formalized proofs.  I personally will stop publishing before I start wasting my time trying to convince a computer that my proofs are correct.

@SamHopkins look at this guy: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicu%C8%99or_Dan

If we are really collecting mayors, one must mention https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sergio_Cecotti of BCOV fame.

@AndyPutman I appreciate the intent of your most recent comment, but it is absurd.  Every part of mathematics depends on verification of results by a comparatively small fraction of the community that (plausibly) uses the result. As you are explaining with your own post, that can and does lead to serious problems for the community.  Formalization can solve that problem.  Maybe you do not want to formalize your proofs.  However, if you found yourself in the same situation as Thomas Hales (for instance), you might change your mind.

@AndyPutman  By the way, I have been running an undergraduate independent study  course this semester about formalizing proofs using Lean.  It is not bad at all.  When combined with the material in an introductory proofs course (which I also teach often), it works very well and helps students understand many of the basic concepts.  Hopefully in the near future the software will be intuitive enough that we can use it for more undergraduate courses (lots of people -- not me! -- are doing hard work to make this possible)

@JasonStarr: Both examples I gave were corrected in the normal way: people were interested enough in the topic that they carefully read the papers and found the errors.  I'm not saying that this was a good situation, but I think it is a good illustration of the self-correcting mechanism underlying the mathematical literature.  I think for most things (not all, but for more than many people claim) you really can with some effort verify for yourself the correctness of the tools you use.  I personally have done that, and in the process I learned a lot of stuff that was useful in other ways.

Most of the big tools that are best treated as black boxes are also part of a mathematical ecosystem, and eventually are understood by a community of people.  The current fad for formalizing proofs tries to take this human element out of math.  For me, that human and community element is fundamental to the reason I do math in the first place.  There are also other issues (e.g. I can't imagine trying to formalize some of the heavily visual and geometric areas I work in), but that's another story and too much for an MO comment thread.

(whether formalizing math is useful as pedagogy is something else all together, and I have no real thoughts on it other than that I personally don't find it compelling enough to try given how many other interesting pedagogical approaches there are that I have not yet experimented with)

The claim that the convolution of unimodal distributions is
unimodal appeared as Theorem 3 of §32 in the very influential book by Gnedenko and Kolmogorov (the Russian original of 1949 of the English translation "Limit Distributions for Sums of Independent Random Variables" of 1954).
As discussed in Appendix II of the English translation, this claim is incorrect. Two simple errors in the "proof" of this claim are indicated there. Of those two, at least the second one, based on an incorrect identity, certainly seems to qualify as "dumb".
The claim and the "proof" appear to have originated in Lapin, A. I. "On some properties of stable laws." Dissertation, in Russian, 1947.
It also appears that the first counterexample to this claim was given by Chung in 1953 (see p. 11 in "Unimodality, Convexity, and Applications" by Dharmadhikari and Joag-dev, 1987).

What was the incorrect identity?

@tparker : This is the first displayed formula on p. 254 (p. 3 of  Appendix II).

Hilbert problem 16, second part asks for an upper estimate of
the number of limit cycles of a polynomial system of
differential equations in dimension 2. For long time
it was believed that Henri Dulac in 1923
proved that the number of limit cycles is finite.
Dulac studied the Poincare map in a neighborhood of
a limit cycle and obtained an infinite asymptotic expansion for it. This derivation occupies a whole book (143 pages). Then he concluded at the very end: since this map
is analytic on $(0,\delta]$, and has an infinite asymptotic expansion as $x\to 0$, it can have only finitely many fixed points, and thus the number of limit cycles is finite (cycles correspond to fixed points of the Poincare map). This is an elementary mistake since the map can be of the form $\phi(x)=x+g(x)$ where $g$ is flat (has zero asymptotic expansion), and thus we can conclude nothing about the number of fixed points near $0$.
This mistake was spotted only in 1980s (probably nobody had patience to read Dulac's book to the very end before), and since then at least two proofs of Dulac's theorem were published, both enormously long and complicated, and I am not sure how well any of them is verified.

The following is a short summary of the attacks on OCB2 in Cryptography.
This is more applied than other answers, but still fits the question fairly well, and has the fun detail that we were only saved from what could have possibly been the most devastating practical failure of cryptography by a patent.
In Cryptography, a common proof technique is that of proofs by reduction. These are essentially "constructive" proofs of implications, which take the general form

Scheme $\Pi$ has property $P\implies$ scheme $F(\Pi)$ has property $Q$.

What "constructive" here means is the combination of

Preserving Running Time: Any algorithm $A$ for breaking property $Q$ of $F(\Pi)$ may be transformed into an algorithm $A'$ for breaking property $P$ of $\Pi$, such that the running times of $A$ and $A'$ are similar, and
Preserving Advantage: For $A$ and $A'$ as above, if $A$ only breaks property $Q$ with some probability $p$, then $A'$ breaks property $P$ with some probability $p'$ not too much smaller than $p$.

Reductions are perhaps the core proof technique in cryptography.
Relevant to the discussion below is their usage in symmetric encryption.
Here, one starts with

a block cipher $\Pi$, roughly encryption for "fixed-length" (e.g. 128 bits) inputs, which
satisfies a weak security property $P$ (typically "Indistinguishabillity under Chosen Plaintext Attack", or IND-CPA. At a high level, this models passive adversaries, which may choose messages $m$ to be encrypted, and view the resulting ciphertexts that are transmitted, but may not modify these ciphertexts in any way),

and produces

a general encryption scheme $F(\Pi)$, which may encrypt messages of arbitrary (not a priori bounded) length, which

satisfies a strong security property $Q$ (for example, in IND-CCA2, one allows an adversary to arbitrarily modify the aformentioned ciphertexts).


For symmetric encryption, the above are typically called "block cipher modes of operation". One often needs not only a transformation $F$ that takes as input a block cipher $\Pi$, but additionally an auxiliary scheme $\Gamma$ called a "Message Authentication Code". I won't discuss this detail further though.
There are many popular modes of operation. The OCB modes have similar performance to "classical" modes, while achieving a stronger security property known as authenticated encryption with associated data (AEAD).
An AEAD cipher takes as input two messages $(m, d)$, where

the message $m$ is kept private (along the lines of IND-CCA2 mentioned above), while
the data $d$ is publicly transmitted, but "authenticated", so an adversary who attempts to modify this (public) data will be caught.

This can be useful when messages $m$ require public components for processing. For example, the data $d$ may contain the ID of which key should be used to decrypt the message. Such data must be public, but should also not be able to be tampered with.
Over roughly a decade, Phil Rogaway developed the OCB Modes (OCB1, OCB2, OCB3) of operation.
They have been very popular. OCB2 was an ISO standard (until the attack referred to below), and (a variant of) OCB3 continues to be one (only OCB2 is known to have a flawed security proof).
OCB3 was selected as a "winner" of the CAESAR competition (a competition run by cryptographers to select a portfolio of cryptographic recommendations for future usage by standardization committees).
These schemes all had reduction-based proofs of security.
This doesn't mean that the schemes are secure, but it should mean that the only "real" way to attack them is to attack their base components $\Pi$, rather than their transformation $F(\Pi)$.
In 2018, Inoue and Minematsu found a simple attack on OCB2, that attacked the transformation $F$ rather than the components $\Pi$. This is to say that Rogaway's proof was wrong.
The way it was wrong may be described simply in a high-level way.
Roughly speaking (and perhaps in a post-hoc way, with knowledge of the attack), for OCB2 one may split $F = G\circ H$ into two parts.

First, one shows that $H(\Pi)$ produces what is known as a tweakable block cipher from a block cipher $\Pi$, and
Then, one shows that $G(\Pi')$ maps a tagged tweakable block cipher to an AEAD scheme.

This is to say that there was a small mismatch between the post-condition of $H$ and pre-condition of $G$.
This small gap lead to a complete failure in the proof, in the sense that OCB2 admitted efficient, near-complete breaks in security, even for secure "base" schemes $\Pi$.
This was missed by several standardization bodies, and many cryptographers (as of 2024, the OCB2 paper has nearly 600 citations).

As mentioned previously, this attack thankfully didn't have much practical impact. Despite OCB2 having many practical benefits compared to competing schemes, Rogaway patented the scheme, and had various licenses for it, namely

Free usage in open-source software,
Paid licenses available in commercial non-military software.

This was not enough for cryptographic library authors (see some discussion here) to widely adopt the OCB modes.
So, the presence of the patents deterred adoptions of OCB modes, which saved us from OCB2 failing — despite its security proof.

I do not resist to mention an extra-mathematical case of the situation you are interested in. From Wikipedia article on Chromosome (the bold characters are mine):

The number of human chromosomes was published in 1923 by Theophilus Painter. By inspection through the microscope, he counted twenty-four pairs, which would mean forty-eight chromosomes. His error was copied by others and it was not until 1956 that the true number, forty-six, was determined by Indonesian-born cytogeneticist Joe Hin Tjio.


And similarly, Aristotle claimed mayflies have 4 legs, rather than 6 (though exactly what constitutes a "leg" makes this a bit ambiguous).

Aristotle also thought, and claimed, that buzzards had three testicles. I think the common feature here is that Aristotle couldn't count.

@DavidA.Craven Maybe he had really bad handwriting?

http://scienceblogs.com/evolvingthoughts/2008/09/16/aristotle-on-the-mayfly/ indicates that Aristotle actually claimed that the mayfly walked on 4 legs, which is correct as the front 2 are not used for walking (on the other hand, the scientific name for the Madagascar Serpent Eagle does in fact mean Good hawk having 3 testicles)

I guess this happens when the title of a question speaks of "research community" without specifying mathematics.

As long as we're piling onto Aristotle, he taught that regular tetrahedra can fill space. https://www.ams.org/notices/201211/rtx121101540p.pdf

I'm surprised no one has yet mentioned a mathematical object sufficiently mainstream that it has its own Wikipedia page: Analytic sets
Wikipedia doesn't mention it, but the existence of these sets flew under the radar for a while; Lebesgue published a paper in which he claimed that the projection onto a line of the intersection of a family of plane sets is the intersection of their projections.
(Hoare, G. T. Q., and N. J. Lord. "‘Intégrate, longueur, aire’the centenary of the Lebesgue integral." The Mathematical Gazette 86.505 (2002): 3-27.)
This is clearly false! Yet it took a few years until it was noticed; in June 1930, Lusin finally published his Leçons sur les ensembles analytiques et leurs applications in which he developed the theory of such sets. Lebesgue himself wrote the preface to the book in which he mentioned his "fruitful error":
A la réflexion, une Préface m'a semblé être le seul endroit où je
pourrais avouer très haut ce que M. Lusin a soigneusement caché:
l'origien de tous les problemès dont it va s'agir ici est une grossiere erreur de mon Memoire sur les fonctions représentables analytiquement. Fructueuse  erreur, que je fus bien inspiré de la commettre!
[Translation: On reflection, a Preface seemed to me to be the only place where I could confess clearly what Mr. Lusin has carefully hidden:
the origin of all the problems that will be discussed here is a gross error in my Memoir on analytically representable functions. A fruitful error, which I was well inspired to commit!]
(Unfortunately, I can't find a link to the original article in which Lebesgue claimed this since the above article refers only to his Oeuvres scientifiques, and a full bibliography seems to be on the internet, only fragments. I looked around, but I wasn't able to find it, neither on gallica.bnf.fr, nor on MathSciNet. Strangely, the article Who discovered analytic sets on Wikipedia mentions none of these facts, which seem important pieces in their discovery.)

Also mentioned here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/898/25028

Thanks for the heads-up. So I was indeed right to be surprised :D At least my answer wasn't completely redundant by contributing some new pieces of information behind the story.

I think that Jules Drach's nonlinear differential Galois theory is an example. It was published as his thesis: "Essai sur une théorie générale de l'intégration et sur la classification des transcendantes", Ann. Sci de l'École Norm. Sup., Serie 3, 15 (1898), pp. 243-384.
Drach continued to publish on this subject, and gave invited lectures to the International Congress of Mathematicians at Cambridge in 1912 and also at Toronto in 1924.
So I think it's safe to say that Drach's work was indeed taken seriously.
However, a major mistake was discovered by Vessiot not long after the publication of the thesis. In brief, the key construct - the "rationality group" - need not exist. In a letter of 3rd October 1898 to Drach, Vessiot went so far as to say that all the proofs must be given anew: "Et dans tous les cas, toutes les démonstrations me paraissent a créer a peu près de toutes pièces."
Was it a "dumb mistake"?  Well, in a letter to Vessiot a few weeks later, Painlevé remarked that anybody who thought about it for five minutes would recognise the problem.
As far as I can discover, Drach's only published response to all this was a footnote in his 1912 ICM lecture acknowledging that in 1898 "Messrs. Painlevé and Vessiot ... had kindly drawn my attention to the ambiguity of certain statements."

The letter from Vessiot to Drach, and from Painlevé to Vessiot are reproduced and translated into English in Pommaret's book Lie Groups and Mechanics,Gordon & Breach 1988.
A. Cogliati in "Early history of infinite continuous groups, 1883–1898", Historia Mathematica 41 (2014) pp. 291-332 states that the topic of the Grand Prix des Sciences Mathématiques for 1902 was selected with Drach's thesis (and its issues) in mind.
He quotes in the verdict of the jury (H. Poincaré, C. Jordan, P. Painlevé, É. Picard and P. Appel) that Vessiot's prize winning paper "fully relieves the lacunae which still afflicted the theory inaugurated by Drach on linear partial differential equations."


Alfred Kempe published a "proof" of the four colour conjecture in 1879. Another "proof" was published by Peter Guthrie Tait in 1880. Percy Heawood debunked Kempe's in 1890, and Julius Petersen debunked Tait's in 1891. But I'm not sure the mistakes count as "dumb".

The OP provides a definition of 'dumb' that allows one to test this, at least on a personal level.  For example, upon looking at these proofs, now that you know that they are wrong, are the mistakes immediately obvious to you?  I suppose one could also question whether the research community was led astray by these false proofs—did they shape the direction of future research, other than, perhaps, by temporarily depressing interest in further attempts at proof?  (None of these questions are rhetorical.)

I'm not a biologist*, but I believe a Kempe chain is a standard part of proofs on graph coloring today. I don't know if they came from Kempe's invalid proof, but if they did, I would say the invalid proof does not satisfy tparker's definition of a "dumb" mistake. *If you know, you know.

Kempe chains do come from his original proof, and can be used to prove a weaker result, I think maybe that at most six colours are needed? Kempe chains are a two-coloured chain of regions that alternate colours inside a larger graph. His idea was to flip the colours in a chain. His "proof" at one point flipped the colours of a red-green and a yellow-blue chain simultaneously, which you cannot do in general. I don't think it's a trivial mistake.

@DavidA.Craven Kempe's technique is enough to prove the Five Colour Theorem, which was done by Heawood once the flaw in Kempe's claim was found. Six colours admits an easier argument by induction and using the fact there is always a a vertex of degree at most 5 in a planar graph.

@DavidRoberts Thanks. I couldn't remember whether it was six or five, so I went conservative. I know we did both in my undergrad course, which was more than 20 years ago!

I was shown the Five Colour Theorem using the Kempe chain at school in the 1970s, and I said then that the same technique could be used to prove the Four Colour Theorem, not realising that I had in effect reproduced Kempe's erroneous proof.  His error (and mine) involved swapping the colours on two chains simultaneously when they needed to be (but could not be) swapped consecutively as they intersected; I am not sure this counts as "dumb".

"Growth in a Time of Debt." Reinhart, Carmen M., and Kenneth S. Rogoff. American economic review 100.2 (2010): 573-578.
A short article in economics, it now has nearly 5500 citations and is notable enough for its own wikipedia page. The article examines the association between national debt and growth of GDP across several countries, and its most important conclusion is that

When gross external debt
reaches 60 percent of GDP, annual growth
declines by about two percent; for levels of
external debt in excess of 90 percent of GDP,
growth rates are roughly cut in half.

When restricted to post-WWII economies, their figure 2 claims even further that GDP growth becomes negative on average if debt exceeds 90%. The result was taken seriously by many economists and politicians and was directly referenced by conservative economic policies in the USA, UK, and EU. They used the Reinhart and Rogoff claim to support spending cuts so that the "deadly" 90% debt ratio could be avoided.
In "Does high public debt consistently stifle economic growth? A critique of Reinhart and Rogoff." Herndon, Thomas, Michael Ash, and Robert Pollin.  Cambridge journal of economics 38.2 (2014): 257-279, it was shown that the Reinhart-Rogoff paper overestimated the growth dependence on debt ratio by a 2.5x factor and despite its short length contained numerous statistical errors. The "dumbest" of these was that when constructing the figures for their main result, the authors had misclicked and inadvertently failed to select a large percentage of the countries and years in their excel spreadsheet. The spreadsheet had not been included in the initial publication but was provided to the researchers by special request.
There's subjectivity regarding whether economics is considered a part of the "mathematics research community", but it's inarguable that a 6-page article which dramatically affected economic policy of multiple world powers over the course of three years due to a Microsoft Excel misclick is exceedingly dumb.

-1. This is not mathematics research.

@user76284 Not constructive.
